# How can I restore configuration files?

Tags: package-management, apt, configuration

I would like to restore LightDM to its default state, because for some reason
`/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` is now an empty file.

Deleting `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` and then running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-greeter` doesn't create a new config file as you might expect.

How can I restore a missing config file?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

1. Find out [what package installed the config file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file):

   ```
   $ dpkg -S unity-greeter.conf
   unity-greeter: /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
   ```

   As you can see, the name of the package is `unity-greeter`.

   If you deleted a directory, like `/etc/pam.d`, you can list every package that added to it by using the directory path:

   ```
   $ dpkg -S /etc/pam.d
   login, sudo, libpam-runtime, cups-daemon, openssh-server, cron, policykit-1, at, samba-common, ppp, accountsservice, dovecot-core, passwd: /etc/pam.d
   ```
2. Run the following command, replacing `<package-name>` with the name of the package:

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" <package-name>
   ```

   And for restoring the directory:

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" $(dpkg -S /etc/some/directory | sed 's/,//g; s/:.*//')
   ```
3. If everything worked as expected, you should get a message:

   ```
   Configuration file `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf', does not exist on system. 
   Installing new config file as you requested.
   ```
4. A Practical example when needing to reinstall all of the PulseAudio configuration files:

   ```
   dpkg -l | awk '/^ii.*pulseaudio/{print$2}' | xargs -n 1 apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall
   ```

Comment: Thank you; I have been wondering about this for years.  It should really be easier to specify, though - is there a bug open somewhere for that?

Comment: I converted this answer to a little script: https://gist.github.com/jameshfisher/10547691

Comment: An extra benefit of `--force-confask` without deleting is that it offers to show the diff between your changes and the original.

Comment: Not tested with Ubuntu, but under Debian to restore config files which are managed by `ucf` the `--force-confmiss` option won't work, you have to use `sudo UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=1 apt-get --reinstall install [pkgname]`.

Comment: Very strange that when I used `-o` I got a "dpkg: error: unknown option -o" error but when I used `--option` instead it worked. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Comment: `dpkg -S` also takes a full path, e.g. `dpkg -S /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. This is probably obvious to most people, but it wasn't to me.

Comment: To check all of your system files for corruption/existence, run `sudo debsums -a -s`.  This will print all files, including config files, from all installed packages, that are missing or changed.  Note that it will show any config files that you changed, so just because a file is shown doesn't necessarily mean something's wrong.

Comment: How very apt - it was pulseaudio.

Comment: Running it in bash script gives `E: Unable to locate package anacron cron e2fsprogs sysstat php-common popularity-contest` (it somehow puts different packages as one package name). How it can be avoided?

Answer (score 47):

For many cases, the default configuration file is provided by a package directly. In such cases, you can extract the specific file from the package, thus easily recovering the file.

To check if a package provides the file, run `dpkg -S` on the full path of the file. For example:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/ssh_config /etc/sudoers
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/ssh/sshd_config
openssh-client: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
sudo: /etc/sudoers
```

## Provided by a package

As we can see, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is not directly provided by any package, but the other two are provided by `openssh-client` and `sudo` respectively. So, if you wished to recover `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, first get the package:

```
apt-get download openssh-client
```

Now, you can either extract the file directly to its intended location, or to its intended location *relative* to the current directory instead of `/`, if you wished to compare and contrast, or manually merge them or something. For the former:

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile openssh-client_*.deb | sudo tar x ./etc/ssh/ssh_config -C /
```

The `-C /` tells `tar` to extract after changing to `/`, which means the target file will get replaced. If you remove it, `tar` will extract to the current directory, meaning `./etc/ssh/ssh_config` will exist in your current directory.

If for some reason `sudo` doesn't work, use `pkexec` instead. If `pkexec` doesn't work either, reboot to recovery mode, mount `/` as `rw`. If *that* doesn't work...

---

## Created by a package

What about `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? It doesn't seem to be provided by any package, so how did it appear?

In this case (and in many other such cases, another example being `/etc/modules`), the file was created using a [package maintainer script](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts) while installation. This is often done when the configuration file needs to be changed due to user responses to queries. OpenSSH, for example, asks if `PermitRootLogin` should be changed to `no`, in newer versions, among other things.

To identify such cases, try greping through the maintainer scripts. Typically you would only need to look `postinst`, but if you don't have any luck with `postinst`, try `preinst` as well:

```
grep -l /etc/ssh/sshd_config /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst
```

In this case, we're in luck:

```
$ grep /etc/ssh/sshd_config /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst -l
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst
```

Only one file matched, and as luck would have it, it contains code to create a [default configuration file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/openssh/trusty/view/head:/debian/openssh-server.postinst#L291):

```
    cat <<EOF > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
EOF
```

Typically, this is what you would see (another example, [`/etc/modules` from `kmod`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/kmod/trusty/view/head:/debian/kmod.postinst#L5)):

```
cat > /path/to/the/file <<EOF
# default contents
EOF
```

So, you can look for this code and get the contents from the script directly.

---

No such script? You can still try poking through the filelists of related packages to see if anything hits, but at this point, I see no easily generalizable method (short of reinstallation on transient environments, like a chroot or a VM or a live USB).

---

In the long run, keep your configuration under version control. Any VCS worth its salt can save the day here, and [the `etckeeper` utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/etckeeper.html) considerably simplifies the task of keeping `/etc` in a VCS.

Answer (score 9):

1. Find the package that owns the configuration file:

   ```
   dpkg --search /etc/path/to/config
   ```

   It will output something similar to:

   ```
   unity-greeter: /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
   ```

   So the package name is `unity-greeter`.
2. Download the package:

   ```
   apt-get download unity-greeter
   ```
3. Then extract its file system tree data to a `.tar` file:

   ```
   dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile unity-greeter_version-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb > pkg.tar
   ```
4. Finally extract only that exact configuration anywhere you want it to be:

   ```
   tar -Oxf pkg.tar ./etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf | sudo tee /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
   ```

   - `./etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` is the file name in our archive.
   - `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` is where I'm sending it to be stored.

---

Or [as @Muru suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files#comment1498847_943680), we can do steps 3 and 4 with a one-liner:

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile unity-greeter_version-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb | sudo tar -x -C / ./etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
```

Comment: If you're simply restoring it back where it belongs, do `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile unity-greeter_version-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb | sudo tar x -C / ./etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf`, so `tar` will cd to `/` before extracting.

Comment: @muru added as an alternative ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1854189) thread on the Ubuntu Forums, it's as simple as running the following in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Comment: I ran that command and this was the output: `dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing`. LightDM wasn't restored to its original configuration either.

Comment: @DoR: Hm... that's odd. Is reinstalling the package an option.

Comment: I reinstalled it (`sudo apt-get --reinstall install lightdm`) and still `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` is empty.

Comment: This is common advice, but it is definitely wrong; it doesn't work for most cases I've tried it on.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem on Ubuntu 17.04.
The postinstall uses a template from `/usr/share/openssh/`.
It checks if rootlogin is enabled or not, sets this option and copies it to `/etc/ssh`. After that it does some ucf and ucfr calls (I don't know what that is for).

Just copy `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/openssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Now adjust your `sshd_config` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work all configuration files. For `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, see [How to restore/recreate etc/nsswitch.conf files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895880/how-to-restore-recreate-etc-nsswitch-conf-files) . It does not seem to be possible to reconstruct that file with `dpkg-reconfigure`.

Comment: I know the original question was about lightdm, but apparently the admins [have decided](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627017/how-do-i-recover-the-default-version-of-some-configuration-file) that this question is about all configuration files

Answer (score -1):

Delete (back) the file and and reinstall `unity-greeter` with `apt-get install --reinstall unity-greeter`.

Comment: This doesn't restore the configuration files.

Comment: It will restore file if everythiing has been deleted/moved (eg. remove /etc/<app> folder in my case).