# How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?

Tags: sudo, visudo

How do I edit an invalid sudoers file? It throws the below error and it's not allowing me to edit again to fix it.

Here is what happens:

```
$ sudo visudo
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 28 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 28
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Comment: great question considering this page creates that error https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout

Comment: Related: [Can sudo be reinstalled after being removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434525/can-sudo-be-reinstalled-after-being-removed)

Comment: If pkexec also doesn't work, you can use Docker surprisingly enough. Link to solution on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/707514/590481  My apologies for hijacking with a comment. I don't have enough rep to answer properly.

Comment: @rusty's comments should upvoted more... under my Ubuntu WSL, the pkexec did not work and the docker trick saved me. ;)

Answer (score 479, accepted):

On a modern Ubuntu system (and many other GNU/Linux distributions), fixing a corrupted `sudoers` file is actually quite easy, and doesn't require rebooting, using a live CD, or physical access to the machine.

To do this via SSH, log in to the machine and run the command `pkexec visudo`. If you have physical access to the machine, SSH is unnecessary; just open a Terminal window and run that `pkexec` command.

Assuming you (or some other user) are authorized to run programs as `root` with PolicyKit, you can enter your password, and then it will run `visudo` as `root`, and you can fix your `/etc/sudoers`.

If you need to edit one of the configuration files in `/etc/sudoers.d` (which is uncommon in this situation, but possible), use `pkexec visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/filename`.

If you have a related situation where you have to perform additional system administration commands as root to fix the problem (also uncommon in this circumstance, but common in others), you can start an interactive root shell with `pkexec bash`. Generally speaking, any non-graphical command you'd run with `sudo` can be run with `pkexec` instead.

(If there is more than one user account on the system authorized to run programs as `root` with PolicyKit, then for any of those actions, you'll be asked to select which one you want to use, before being asked for your password.)

---

If that doesn't work--for example, if there are no users authorized to run programs as root via PolicyKit--then boot from an Ubuntu live CD (like the CD you probably used to install Ubuntu) and mount the filesystem for the installed system. You can do this by running `sudo parted -l` to view your partitions--there is probably just one ext4 partition, and that's the root filesystem.

Suppose the installed Ubuntu system's root filesystem is on `/dev/sda1`. Then you could mount it with `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. Then you can edit the installed system's sudoers file with `sudo nano -w /mnt/etc/sudoers`. Or, even better, you can edit it with

```
sudo visudo -f /mnt/etc/sudoers
```

(which will prevent you from saving a sudoers file with incorrect syntax).

Comment: pkexec /usr/sbin/visudo worked on debian 7

Comment: Couldn't they also just boot into recovery mode?

Comment: HOLY COW! Thanks a LOT! Saved my bacon. Added a file as suggested into etc/sudoers.d/ directory USING A REGULAR TEXT EDITOR (D-O-N-T__D-O__T-H-A-T!!!). Lost all ability to do elevated privileges, INCLUDING, editing the offending file. This helped edit the file. Weird though, I had to edit /etc/sudoers first, then it found the errors in the other file and opened that for me. EVEN WEIRDER, the directive in /etc/sudoers file 'inlcudedir /etc/sudoers.d' was commented out, and it still includes it.

Comment: @Dennis Somewhat confusingly, `#include` directives in `sudoers` files are treated specially; the leading `#` does not cause the rest of the line to be interpreted as a comment, in that case. As [`man sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) says: "The pound sign (‘#’) is used to indicate a comment (unless it is part of a #include directive or unless..." See also [visudo: #includedir sudoers.d](http://web.archive.org/web/20140702142556/http://lzone.de/visudo%20includedir%20sudoers.d) (archived from http://lzone.de/blog/).

Comment: @EliahKagan what if I don't even have pkexec installed?

Comment: @Lucas `pkexec` is installed by default on most desktop Ubuntu systems, though not on many server and minimal systems. If you don't have `pkexec`, you cannot use the `pkexec`-based way, as you'd have to first fix the problem in order to install `pkexec`. (Manual, *non-root* installations by copying `pkexec` and supporting files from another machine will not give `pkexec` the ability to perform actions as root.) So if you have this problem and don't have `pkexec`, you'll instead have to use a less convenient method, like booting into recovery mode (as Seth suggests) or using a live CD/DVD/USB.

Comment: My user is sudoer but i got this error: _Error executing command as another user: Not authorized_

Comment: It also works on RHEL 7!

Comment: Note: if you're not running a graphical linux flavor you might get ` GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie`. Do not lose hope; see https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012 for a solution

Comment: I don't have visudo installed. So I did pkexec vim. Then it shows the list of users and asks for password. When I provide password, it throws  error as " Error executing command as another user: Not authorized". Please help

Comment: `pkexec bash` works on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, ``pkexec visudo`` asks for a password, which does not accept the correct password. It throws an "AUTHENTICATION FAILED" error.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04: Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory

Comment: AUTHENTICATION FAILED fix:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/799669/etc-sudoers-file-corrupted-and-i-cant-run-pkexec-visudo-over-ssh?newreg=738961109f804005b8f7188bbcdf98f3

Comment: Adding an answer in case this happens in a WSL Ubuntu system, and you are stuck in a regular user; not sudo.
Close the WSL terminal and execute the below command in CMD. "ubuntu1804 config --default-user root" for Ubuntu 18.04 or "ubuntu config --default-user root" for versions below.
Next login will be on root

Comment: `pkexec visudo` worked on Ubuntu. Life saver

Comment: This works, but beware of this bug: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012

Comment: `polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie` - not sure what is the problem? (Debian) __UPDATE__ [Fix here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012)

Comment: HOLY COW!! This was a *FRESH INSTALL* and /etc/sudoers had the line "@includedir /etc/sudoers.d"!!! Clever, that. Fortunately, visudoers ignored the "." in "README.tmp" so I could understand the problem. Why isn't _everyone_ experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 79):

Always use `visudo` to edit your sudoers file, never edit it directly yourself. It will prevent you saving it to disk unless it validates.

Comment: hindsight is 20/20

Comment: It won't prevent disaster. It's easy enough to validly deny yourself.

Comment: Can visudo be used by scritps? If so, how?

Comment: I don't have visudo installed. So I did pkexec vim. Then it shows the list of users and asks for password. When I provide password, it throws error as " Error executing command as another user: Not authorized". Please help

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka Copied from another comment: Note: if you're not running a graphical linux flavor you might get ` GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie`. Do not lose hope; see github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012 for a solution

Answer (score 34):

Type in:

```
pkexec visudo
```

Then change last line

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers
```

To:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: I've noticed that removing the leading `#` from `#includedir` causes syntax errors, the `#` is part of the directive, at least on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: That just saved me a lot of headache.  Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I don't have visudo installed. So I did pkexec vim. Then it shows the list of users and asks for password. When I provide password, it throws error as " Error executing command as another user: Not authorized". Please help

Answer (score 26):

When this happens to a non-GUI system (your production server, maybe) the `pkexec` fails with this error message:

```
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
```

In this situation, using `pkttyagent` can be helpful. If you want to remove a corrupted file in `sudoers.d` directory, use this:

```
pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) | pkexec rm /etc/sudoers.d/FILENAME
```

If you want to recover the default `/etc/sudoers`, you can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alitoufighi/679304d9585304075ba1ad93f80cce0e) to copy the default configurations, putting it in a non-root accessed place (e.g. your `$HOME`). Then, you can overwrite your sudoers file:

```
pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) | pkexec cp ~/sudoers /etc/sudoers
```

**NOTE:** Using this approach, after running your command, probably your access to the shell will be gone. But I'm sure losing one shell session is much better than losing your server! (According to the [manpage](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/pkttyagent.1.html), this is the normal behavior: When its services are no longer needed, the process can be killed.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Comment: This is great material, thanks mate!

Comment: Thanks so much... just saved an embedded device from needing reflashing ;)

Comment: lifesaver! thanks

Comment: I get super excited each time I get a comment here. I'm very glad to be helpful guys.

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked after I passed `--disable-internal-agent` to `pkexec`. Was getting `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject`

Comment: Underrated answer. Genuinely saved my life

Answer (score 17):

if anyone else like me didn't have *pkexec* installed, or was not able to run vi, visudo, nano or any other editor to change sudoers file you can be sure with this process.. I was saved with this:

- reboot
- hold shift key while booting to have option for recovery mode (enter it)
- enter command line as root (second last option at my grub menu)
- remount boot device for rw, and apply exec right for user, and edit file

  ```
  mount -n -o remount,rw /
  chmod u+x /etc/sudoers
  visudo /etc/sudoers
  ```

fix that mistake and be happy :)

Comment: While pkexec solution suggested by @eliah-kagan seems to be easier, this one is more universal. On my machine it turned out that there is no pkexec installed and of course I could not install it because sudo apt-get install pkexec somehow did not work.

Comment: Also within this approach I would use `visudo` instead `nano /etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 9):

If you messed up your `sudoers` file, you'll need to:

- Reboot into recovery mode (hit escape during boot, choose the recovery mode option on the grub screen)
- Choose the 'Enable networking' option (if you don't your filesystem will be mounted as read-only. who knew)
- Chosee the 'Drop to root shell' option
- run `visudo`, fix your file
- Reboot with normal grub option

source :- http://mario.net.au/content/recover-etcsudoers-ubuntu-1204

Comment: Hi, does it removes the iptables, files of existing system ?

Answer (score 6):

For WSL users, accessing a bad `sudoers` is much more straightforward:

```
wsl.exe -u root visudo
```

If you cannot recover the file manually this way, you can reset it to the default installed version (adapted from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/67028/1165986)) with:

```
wsl.exe -u root -e apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" sudo
```

**Important**:  This will reset *all* configuration files associated with `sudo`, including other customizations done in `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Comment: Thanks for adding this aspect to the portfolio of answers. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild Certainly.  Would you do me a favor and let me know if my subsequent edit is okay?  I'm not an `apt` expert, but that should force reinstallation of the `sudoers` files, right?  Note that I did test this by deleting my own `/etc/sudoers` and recovering it with that command.

Comment: I'm also not *that* much of an expert, but it looks right. Maybe @steeldriver can confirm?

Comment: I confirm this saving an entire day at work 

Comment: @FonzTech Thank you for the confirmation, and glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong #include sudoer.d
removing #include sudoer.d won't make any difference.

But please make sure you don't have any syntax errors.
I had same issue but and spent hours to fix and just figured out they are syntax errors.
Refer to manual and make them right.

For example 
Say your username is : dolly
I used following which is wrong

```
 dolly ALL = (ALL) ALL NO PASSWD: ALL
```

correct syntax is

```
dolly ALL = (ALL) ALL //give permission to everything, not good
```

or

```
dolly ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/thurderbird //good, give specific permission
```

hope this helps

Comment: A better approach than making sure you don't have syntax errors is to always use [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) when editing these files, which makes sure you don't have syntax errors for you, before it modifies file. `visudo` is not just for editing `/etc/sudoers`--it will also create and edit files in `/etc/sudoers.d`. It will also work with whatever text editor you want. See [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) for details.

Comment: As for giving specific permission, please note that this is only useful for very simple commands/apps, because any sufficiently complex app (including `thunderbird`, which should never be run as root anyway) will effectively give the user full system access when run as root. Even seemingly simple functionality opens the door to full root access. For example, a user who can run a program that can save a file to an arbitrary location as root can gain full root access (they can install their own `/etc/sudoers`, or if syntax limitations prevent that, they can install their own `/etc/crontab`).

Answer (score 3):

run recovery mode then type this

```
chown -R root:root /etc/sudoers.d
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx /etc/sudoers.d/
chmod u=r,g=r,o= /etc/sudoers.d/*
```

only the group and user root should have read privelege

Answer (score 2):

You can also login as root on a `tty` console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> (<kbd>Fn</kbd> from 1 to 6) and run `visudo`.

Answer (score 2):

```
pkexec visudo
```

then revert your mistakes

Comment: not necessary to use pkexec

Comment: @Braiam `visudo` has to be run as root. If `sudo` doesn't work, `pkexec` sometimes does. This is covered by [my earlier answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/73872/22949)... but it is a correct answer, `visudo` by itself (when not run as root) will not work, and there may be value in correct, brief answers even when their recommendations overlap considerably with other answers. Of course, if one goes into recovery mode, that's a root shell and then neither `sudo` nor `visudo` is necessary for commands like `pkexec`. Maybe that's what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your boot entry while in grub as well.

Simply reboot your pc, and wait for grub to show. Then press "e" on the "Ubuntu" entry to edit it.

Look for a line with "linux = " or "kernel = " and simply add an "single" to the end of that line.

Then press F10 to boot this temporarily modified boot entry.
This will give you a shell (without GUI) with root rights and you can edit the sudoers file with s.th. like nano /etc/sudoers back to its previous state.

Then reboot and its done.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 running on a VirtualBox (shouldn't make a difference), the above methods didn't work for me (invalid row in the end of the file). What did work was:

1. Restart the VirtualBox
2. Let it boot normally, until it asks for your username & password in the console
3. Login normally with your username
4. Then when you end up in the console (provided your box doesn't boot into a GUI), simply give the command `su -` and then give your own username's password.
5. It should now end up in `root@ubuntu-xenial:~#` prompt, if the `/etc/sudoers` isn't too broken or empty. Not sure what would happen in that case.
6. Then you can simply run `visudo` and fix the file.
7. Then `Ctrl + X` and it will prompt to Save modified buffer. Press `Y` and `Enter`
8. Restart the box and it should work now.

In case your `/etc/sudoers` is empty or missing something, and you can edit it, then here's the contents of mine:

```
Defaults env_reset
Defaults mail_badpass
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Your step 4 does not make sense, it only works when your root password is same as your normal user.

Comment: Which is very common in a local VM.

Answer (score 1):

Good practice: a backup terminal window and run `sudo su` there. On another termianl run visudo or sudo vim /etc/sudoers. If anything goes wrong, go back to terminal one and fix the file. You may ask, why not just run `sudo su` before `visudo` in one terminal? This works as well, but has higher risk of you closing the terminal before you know it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way simpler solution. Without rebooting, recovery mode, or `pkgexec` (`pkgexec` didn't work and have no idea why or how I should use it), simply do:

```bsh
su root # switch to root user, without using sudo (which is broken at this point)
your_favorite_editor /etc/sudoers # e.g. nano
```

And then just fix the syntax error!

Comment: What's with the downvote? Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This answer is actually working. I wonder why the downvote !!

Comment: I suggest that downvote should come with an explanation. Otherwise, people can exploit it and, even worse, disallow a valid answer.

Comment: I think the downvote came from the land that running this command requires root to have a password, which by default it doesn't.

Comment: Ah, so the thing is that it doesn't work for ubuntu. So many questions on this board are applicable to linux in general, however, that I often fail to think about distro differences (and of course, this is the main thing that comes up on google when you search this problem).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for the new wave of WSL-based Linux VMs. When I locked myself out of my debian-based WSL2 VM (Pengwin) which didn't have pkexec and the root password was not set, here's what I found fixed the problem:

- Open a Windows Powershell as administrator (right-click 'Run as Administrator')
- Set the default user on the VM to be root (because it won't ask for a password) per [this how-to](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-set-default-user-switch-user-and-remove-a-user-for-wsl):

```
<distro.exe> config --default-user root
```

Example:

```
ubuntu1804.exe config --default-user root
```

or

```
pengwin.exe config --default-user root
```

- Re-launch your distro.
- You should now be root and can go fix your sudo problem.
- Repeat the process to set the default user back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can bind the /etc volume into docker like that:

`docker run -it --rm -v /etc:/etc_host ubuntu bash`

2. You gained root access. Then you can change the permissions of `/etc/sudoers` to 777:

`chmod 777 /etc/sudoers`

3. Edit, fix the file and save it with any editor:

`vim /etc/sudoers`

4. Change the permissions of `/etc/sudoers` to default 440:

`chmod 440 /etc/sudoers`

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to reboot the server, you can reboot it and catch it at the grub prompt for Ubuntu. Press 'e' to edit the grub boot config.

Find the line that starts with linux and is indented, then go to the end of that line, and add a space then `init=/bin/bash`. Next press F10 to boot the server. At the root shell prompt enter `mount -o remount,rw /` and press enter.

Now you have access as root to modify the */etc/sudoers* or */etc/sudoers.d/filename*.

Once you have finished modifying the files as needed, enter `reboot -f` and the server will reboot as normal, and your sudo issues should be resolved.