# "no valid sudoers sources found, quitting" error, how to fix it?

Tags: server, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify a invalid /etc/sudoers file? It throws out an error and not allowing me to edit again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)

at the time of running sudo command i got the following error:

"sudo: can't open /etc/sudoers.d/README: Permission denied

> > > /etc/sudoers: /etc/sudoers.d/README near line 23 <<<
> > >       sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 23
> > >       sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting"

due to this error i can't use the sudo command please help me ...