# Cannot run bash script permission denied

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo

I'm running a bash script from terminal like

```
sudo sh /usr/local/ControlPanel/web/bin/login.sh admin myPassword
```

***login.sh***

```
#! /bin/bash

Username=$1;
Password=$2;

algorithm=$(grep $Username /etc/shadow | awk -F'$' '{print $2}')
salt=$(grep $Username /etc/shadow | awk -F'$' '{print $3}' | awk -F: '{print $1}')
password=$(grep $Username /etc/shadow | awk -F'$' '{print $4}' | awk -F: '{print $1}')

hashed='$'$algorithm'$'$salt'$'$password;
algorithmSalt='$'$algorithm'$'$salt;

plaintext=$(python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("'$Password'", "'$algorithmSalt'")')

if [[ $hashed == "$plaintext" ]]; then 
    echo "1|You have successfully loggedin.";
else
    echo "0|Incorrect username or password.";
fi
```

***/etc/sudoers.d/admin***

```
admin   ALL=(ALL)   ALL
admin   ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/local/ControlPanel/web/bin/*
```

***Without adding sudo I got the following error message***

```
grep: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

***After adding sudo I got the following error message***

```
/etc/sudoers.d/admin: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/admin near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Btw.: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: @Cyrus I tried without `sh` too

Comment: Please use `visudo` so it tells you what mistakes there are: `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/admin`

Comment: So really your question boils down to [“no valid sudoers sources found, quitting” error, how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81051/no-valid-sudoers-sources-found-quitting-error-how-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sudoers Error**:  Anytime you're modifying the ***sudoers*** file, only edit it with `visudo` which will sanity check your changes and stop you from cutting your own head off.  If you bork the ***sudoers*** file, could totally hose your access.

**Permissions Error**: This error can be a bit of a red herring...

I was just executing a script with `sudo` that kept failing with "***permission denied***" errors. I was sure it should have worked.

The reason why it was failing?  I forgot to `chmod 700` the file.  As Homer Simpson would say, ***D'Oh!***

So it was *sort of* a permissions error, but only as related to the ***mode*** of the file, rather than ***ownership*** of it.

Hope this helps others having Homer Simpson moments ;-)