# Why does my machine suddenly not allow the "sudo" command?

Tags: sudo

I was working on my machine. I did some Clamav Virus definition updates, ran clamav and everything worked fine using `sudo`.

Suddenly afterwards though, my machine started saying that

```
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

What in the world is going on?

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  (in case relevant)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify a invalid /etc/sudoers file? It throws out an error and not allowing me to edit again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot explain why it happened, but I can propose how to solve.

Check if the file `/etc/sudoers` still exists.

If the answer is no, download the `sudo` package with

```
cd
apt-get download sudo
```

then start in recovery mode, choose to run a root shell from the menu that BusyBox shows, and from command line run

```
mv /home/ray/sudo*.deb /var/apt/cache/archives/
apt-get purge sudo
apt-get install sudo
```

where I assumed `/home/ray` is your home directory.