# Messed up visudo - can't edit the file anymore

Tags: sudo, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify a invalid /etc/sudoers file? It throws error and not allowing to edit again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-error-and-not-allowing-to-e)

I really did some very stupid stuff.

I did a `sudo visudo` and wanted to add the following line:

```
%admin ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/tar
```

so users can execute `/bin/tar` without the need to sudo.

But stupid me **replaced** the line

```
%admin ALL = (ALL)ALL
```

So basically that means I'm totally locked out. Everytime I try a `sudo visudo` I get

*"Sorry, user admin is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/visudo' as root on myhost"*

I only can tar. Great.

Is there any way to get my root rights back?

Comment: You're right, the answer there should solve the problem. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way would be to boot your system from live cd, mount your root file system and modify its /etc/sudoers file to fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I did (got the solution some minutes before your answer from Bruno's linked question above) and it worked. So, kudos to you, too ;-)