# How to fix sudo after "chmod -R 777 /usr/bin"?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, chmod

I entered `chmod -R 777 /usr/bin` and now sudo is not working.

It says `sudo must be setuid root`.

Some advice online said to run `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`.

On entering `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo` it shows an `opened in readonly mode` error.

Comment: You must be root to run those commands

Comment: Manoj Kumar: Did [the `pkexec` method in my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/139182/22949) (which you've marked as accepted) solve this problem for you? I've become convinced that, as Damien Roche and Oli have commented, this method does not actually work after a `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/bin` command *has successfully completed.* Like `sudo`, `pkexec` has to be setuid root to work. (I'm not sure why, as it uses the polkit *service*, but it does.) However, I think I've heard other people say this has worked for them, which is curious! Had you pressed Ctrl+C before the `777` chmod command finished?

Comment: Hello. This method actually has worked for me after I accidentally successfully ran `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/bin`, but only after logging into the `root` account.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> <sup>*Accepted status notwithstanding, I'm now convinced **this answer is wrong**. (I hope to improve it soon, after consulting with the OP about the accept.) I think I recall others saying this worked, but I believe their problems were at least slightly different. The method described herein remains valuable for some situations where `chmod -R 777 /usr/bin` is interrupted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or otherwise does not complete. But once it does, **`pkexec` is un-setuid'd too and it won't work any better than `sudo`**, as Damien Roche and Oli have rightly commented.*</sup>

On an Ubuntu desktop system, [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html) is installed, so **[`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) can be used to repair a broken `sudo` executable or `sudoers` file**. You do not need to boot into recovery mode and you do not need to boot from a live CD. You don't even need to reboot.

In this case, run the following commands:

```
pkexec chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
pkexec chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-anderror-and-not-allowi) for more information.

Comment: `pkexec must be setuid root`! What a nightmare!

Comment: As Damien points out, the problem with this approach is `pkexec` is in exactly the same predicament as `sudo`. It's normally setuid and lives in `/usr/bin`. I've tested it and this just doesn't work after `chmod -R 777 /usr/bin`.

Comment: @DamienRoche, Oli: I'm sorry for not fixing this ***way*** sooner! You're both right. I'm unsure why `pkexec` has to be setuid root to work (doesn't it work through the polkit daemon like other non-setuid processes?), but **it does need that.** I've commented on the question to see if the OP (who accepted this) can shed light on what, if anything, is right or helpful about this answer. And I've added a temporary banner to the top of this post so I don't further mislead. *If* this answer continues to exist, its improved form will probably incorporate some info currently in that banner.

Comment: You could just use `su`, which is located under /bin

Comment: @FliiFe Fixing the permissions (or ownership) of files in `/usr/bin` requires root privileges, but you cannot `su` to root on most Ubuntu systems because root logins are disabled by default. Unlike `sudo` and `pkexec`, when you use `su` to get a root shell or to run a command as root, you have to provide root's password, not your own. But root has no password by default in Ubuntu (which is to say that password-based authentication for root will always fail, *not* that entering a blank password would work). See [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for details.

Comment: @EliahKagan Ah, yeah. Didn't really think about this. I had this issue on a debian server (which you have to set up using root account).

Answer (score 4):

Even when running from the live CD / Pendrive, you must prefix your `chmod` command with `sudo`. So your steps will be like the following:

1. boot from a live CD / Pendrive
2. check whether your disk was already automounted (and where to). If not, mount it (see below)
3. use `sudo chmod 0755 <path>` to adjust the permissions

How to figure out where your disk is mounted: from a terminal window, run `mount` (without arguments). This will list up all mounted devices. Check for the `type` listed -- you can skip everything not using a "real file system" (your disk probably uses either ext3 or ext4 -- you can for sure skip things like proc, sysfs and the like). If something sounds promising (looking like `/dev/sda1 on /media/sda1 type ext3`), check its contents using `ls /media/sda1` to see if it's that.

If it is not mounted, you can check with the `/dev` entries where the disk could be (using `ls /dev/ |grep '/dev/sd` to check for available devices; your disk should look like `/dev/sdaX`, `/dev/sdbX` or the like -- with X being a number). Compare this with the list of mounted devices. If it's not there, try to mount it and check its contents (as shown above). To mount it, first create a mountpoint, e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/mydisk`, then try to mount the device using `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mydisk` and check its contents using `ls /mnt/mydisk`.

Once you get the right disk there, you can go to change the permissions back on your usr dir: `sudo chmod 0755 /mnt/mydisk/usr`.

Now you still might be in trouble if you originally ran the `chmod` command recursively, using the `-R` parameter. In that case you can either try to fix each entry manually -- or you can go straight for a fresh install...

Comment: I tried to create mount point, but I got an error which read **mount point mnt/mydisk does not exists** is mydisk to be replaced with some thing and just for the record i wrote `mount /dev/sda /mnt/mydisk` from `root@Ubuntu:/dev#`

Comment: You did a) create that mount point (directory) before issuing the mount command (as described) and b) took care for the *leading* slash as well? Try `mkdir -p /mnt/mydisk && mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mydisk` (I don't think you have no partitions on `/dev/sda`, so you must have missed the partition number as well. Make sure you specify the correct device (or mount will fail).

Answer (score 1):

I think Mat's correct, you must be root to add the bit to /usr/bin, but of course sudo is broken. If you have a root password you can use that to logon as root and then fix the permissions with the above command. If you don't, however, (and I don't either) it would probably be best to:

- boot from a Linux live CD
- become root there
- mount the partition with the above system
- then straighten out the permissions on that file system using a terminal.

Root is always user number 0 so root on any system can make changes allowed to root on other file systems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much knowledge. But these steps solved my problem even without restarting my machine. Follow these steps:

```
su root
<enter root password>
cd /usr
chmod -R 755 *
```

Comment: You are missing at least a "cd" command. If you do it like this you are doing the "chmod" on the home dir for root. That will make things worse.

Comment: thaks... edited my answer... i was in /usr folder

Comment: This only works, if a password is set for `root`, which is not the default configuration of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to set permissions for my local scripts, I broke the sudo permission and changed ownership, by mistake. I was able to change back the ownership of sudo to root by doing the following:

**Step 1:** Switch to **ubuntu recovery mode**. If you are unaware of the process, you can refer an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/172346/223901

**Step 2:** Once in recovery mode, select **root - Drop to root shell prompt**

**Step 3:** Do the following commands

```
mount -o remount,rw /
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
reboot
```

Wait for your system to boot **normally** and you will see the ownership of sudo back to root.

Answer (score 0):

ramsudharsan is quite right ...
In my case Ubuntu 20.04

**Step 1:** Switch to **ubuntu recovery mode**. If you are unaware of the process, you can refer an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/172346/223901
My machine → reboot and [Esc] after splash screen. A little tricky, but after a few attemps GRUB show up ...

**Step 2:** Once in recovery mode, select **root - Drop to root shell prompt**

**Step 3:** Do the following commands

```
# mount -o remount,rw / → on my machine works without! 

chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo 

chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo 

reboot
```

**Step 4:** After normal reboot/system start

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/[files from the list below]
```

also the other files (no complet list):
/usr/bin:

- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      84K Jul 15  2021 chfn*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      52K Jul 15  2021 chsh*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      39K Mär  7  2020 fusermount*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      87K Jul 15  2021 gpasswd*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root     310K Okt 11  2019 info*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      55K Jul 21  2020 mount*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      44K Jul 15  2021 newgrp*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      67K Jul 15  2021 passwd*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      31K Mai 26  2021 pkexec*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      67K Jul 21  2020 su*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root     163K Jan 19  2021 sudo*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      39K Jul 21  2020 umount*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      26K Jan 11  2021 xdg-open*
- -rwsr-xr-x  1 root root       30 Nov 12  2017 xlinks2*

/usr/sbin/:
*-rwsr-xr-x  1 root dip     386K Jul 23  2020 pppd*

/usr/lib/policykit-1/:
*-rwsr-xr-x   1 root root  23K Mai 26  2021 polkit-agent-helper-1*

Thanks to the recovery mode, there is no need for a reinstallation! ...