# Cannot use sudo command, changed permission of /usr folder

Tags: 12.04, permissions, root, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get back SUDO into working condition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127446/how-to-get-back-sudo-into-working-condition)

Here's how I messed up my ubuntu, I wanted to change file permissions of `/usr` folder and I did that by taking root privilege

```
 sudo -i
```

I changed the file permission and logged back as my home user, but now I am not able to use `sudo` command.

I tried to change the permissions back by using `chown` amd `chmod` command but that does not seem to work, I even tried running Ubuntu live via Pendrive but I don't know how to get to the filesystem (in which ubuntu is installed) via terminal can anyone help me out here? Help me to get those permissions back to normal?