# How can I start Ubuntu in Safe Mode?

Tags: boot, startup

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 on an Acer AX1430G desktop. Everything went fine until I installed the additional ATI driver.

When I rebooted the computer, my monitor gives a "signal out of range" error because I believe the video is being detected at a higher resolution than the monitor supports. How can I force Ubuntu to start up in a lower resolution so that I can adjust display properties. I've already tried editing the `/etc/default/grub` and un-commenting `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` line. I know in Windows, you can press <kbd>F8</kbd> on boot to go into a safe video mode so I'm looking for the equivalent in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 79):

To start Ubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode) hold down the <kbd>left Shift</kbd> key as the computer starts to boot. If holding the Shift key doesn't display the menu press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key repeatedly to display the GRUB 2 menu.  From there you can choose the recovery option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or what, but I can't seem to catch the boot up process at the right time with either the shift or escape keys. I never get a boot menu. Not sure what I could be missing.

Comment: Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> helped to recover 15.04 grub screen, thanks.

Comment: ESC worked for me

Comment: Left Shift for Linux Mint Tricia 19.3

Comment: Does not work for me-it only shows gnu prompt

Answer (score 2):

On 12.10 the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by pushing the SHIFT & ESC keys, but it didn't seem to work until the second boot load screen that comes after the screen where you have the option to press f12, DEL etc.

Answer (score 2):

os : elementary os hera (ubuntu derivative)

-method 1

first boot:

press the `escape` key to enter the startup menu then enter normally the os `login manager` , then `restart`

second boot:

 press the `shift` key , it will redirect you to the `gnu grub screen`

-method 2

`turn the power on` then `press&hold` the `shift` key , then one simple keystroke at the `ESC` key