# Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with AMD radeon HD 3870 Error

Tags: 12.04, ati, msi

I'm very new to ubuntu. I try to change my desktop for Ubuntu because I'm bored with windows 7 and I'm try to learn about ubuntu.
First I'm try Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. After i choose "Instal ubuntu" my computer restart and I getting error "Hyper Transport Synch Flood Error".

I change my instal from CD to USB bootable device, disable HPET and all integrated device, underclock my cpu, increase the voltage, but i'm still get the error.
So I'm trying the older version 10.7, But I'm getting the same error.

When my friend lend his VGA (AMD HD 4850), I can instal it without any error.
After finish installing, I swap to my AMD HD 3870, It can't boot into ubuntu again. When I change into 4850 again, it can boot normally

I read the kernel support AMD 3870, it has the same kernel support with 4850 so i don't think it's kernel fault in this problem.

I don't know to solve this problem, maybe someone can help me with this problem....
Thanks in advance...

ps: when I try to install openSUSE 10.3 I get no error, But when I try openSUSE 12.2 I get the same error as ubuntu.

my computer spec :

AMD phenom II 550
MSI 770-G45
Memory GSKILL DDR3 2x4gb 
AMD Radeon 3870
Seagate 250GB
Seasonic GOLD X 650Watt

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to take down the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and install 10.04, since I also have a ATI Radeon HD 3870 and I'm tired all the time to configure the driver. I got angry and now downloading Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

P.S. On Ubuntu 10.04 LTS more manuals than 12.04 :D

P.P.S. Sorry if I write with mistakes. I am Russian, and understand very little English, so I used Google.

Comment: Thank you skuyall, are your system work fine in 10.04?

update : when i install in my laptop, it installed with no problem , but it had problem when it shut down..
it freeze in shut down loading screen... 
maybe I'm try the stable version neither 12.04

My Laptop MSI GX633 ( Turion Ultra 64, 4gb Memory, Nivdia Cuda GT 130 )

Comment: @Handoko Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is going to better than 12.04. But the problem with drivers is the same - after installing AMD Catalyst start lags. I created a question on this issue. I hope me can help. And at the expense of your problem, I do not know, because I also recently started using Ubuntu.

Comment: My question ---> http://askubuntu.com/questions/222935/problems-with-amd-driver-for-ati-radeon-hd-3870-ubuntu-10-04

Answer (score 0):

Try Safe/Recovery mode and see if this helps your GPU?

[How can I start in safe mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode).

It seems like you said you did not have that problem when running from your live usb. Is that accurate? If safe mode does not work try a Live installation directly to your disk. It seems I had that option when creating a live USB but I passed. In my case it was feasible since I have a small SSD dedicated to Linux only.