# Problems with AMD driver for ATI Radeon HD 3870

Tags: 10.04, drivers, ati, radeon, 32-bit

For some reason after installing the drivers for the video card ATI Radeon HD 3870, start lags. Slows scrolling, sometimes flash player and games. I'm tired. At first it was all in 12.04, and recently installed 10.04 and the same thing happens.

Help, please. Maybe it's not the drivers, but in the Ubuntu or Compiz?

10.04 32-bit (kernel 2.6.32-45)
AMD Athlon 64 X2 5200+
ATI Radeon HD 3870
1 GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the open-source Radeon driver that comes with Ubuntu or did you choose to install the propriatary one (by Running Software Sources and clicking on Additional Drivers tab)?

Also, the Unity interface does rely on your 3D and can slow down things a little for such an old graphics card, maybe trying Xubuntu or Lubuntu would help also...

Comment: I use proprietary drivers. I did not know that there are Open Source driver. They can try? Where I can download them?

My graphics card is not so old that was not supported by Unity 3D. Especially, right now I use Ubuntu 10.04 with Gnome, but lag does not stop.