# Boot problems after upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, boot, upgrade

I am not an experienced Ubuntu user.  I updated my existing 12.04 until no more updates were available and then I chose to upgrade my system to version 12.10.  All went well (or at least I thought it did) until I was prompted to "Restart" the system.  Once I restarted the system I could hear my HDD doing its thing and then saw the screen come on and it said something about either waiting for something to happen (which I chose to do) or press "S" to skip mounting or something like that (I couldn't read it fast enough).  Anyhow, the computer locked up and it wouldn't boot into Ubuntu.  I powered the system down and restarted it hoping to see the message again, but it didn't return.  It just locked up during the boot process and I haven't seen my login screen again.

I have a dual boot configuration with Windows Vista Home Premium (32-bit) and I have never had a problem upgrading in the past.  My processor is an AMD 64-bit and I have always used the 64-bit version of Ubuntu with no problems.

I would appreciate your help in this matter.

Sincerely,

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

The message asking you to press <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>M</kbd> might be this one:

[image]

I suppose that it could not mount one of your Disk Drive.

This could be cause by:

- an error in your file `/etc/fstab` *(this file list how to mount your drives)*
  => to solve it, reboot your PC [with Recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/172346/32413), in recovery mode menu:

  1. go to **Grub** option, it will give a message like **Updating grub will mount your system in read/write mode**. Just chose **yes** to mount your system in read/write mode. It will update your grub and will exit from **Grub** menu.
  2. after go to **root** option and login. Execute following commands:

     ```
     $ blkid
     ```

     <sub>*this should give you the UUID of your Disk*</sub>

     ```
     $ cat /etc/fstab
     ```

     <sub>*this should give you the content of your `fstab` file*</sub>

     Check that your Disk UUID is listed in there.
     **Then please edit your question adding the content of your `fstab` file to help identify the source of the problem**.
- or caused by a physical wire disconnected, yes it happens sometimes (as you are mentioning a weird noise on 1st reboot)