# Can't Start Ubuntu After Updating Video Card Drivers

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, gpu-driver

I have an Nvidia GeForce GT 645.

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 without issue, but was unable to launch Steam.  I tried switching the driver inside the Software & Updates screen, but no matter which selection I made, the result was the same.  Steam wouldn't run.

I followed instructions I found on the internet and ran the following:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update sudo
>
> apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

All completed without error.  Upon rebooting, Ubuntu displays an error message pop-up window.  There are a few options, but no matter what I pick, nothing seems to happen.  One option is to continue in low-res mode, but if I select it, nothing happens.  It also says I can revert to an old configuration, but when I select that option, it brings me to the same screen.  It doesn't seem to actually do anything.

I'm able to get online using the Ubuntu install USB...but I'm afraid I'm in over my head.  I don't want to reinstall because I've spent a good ~10 hours or so getting things to work, I don't care if I can't run Steam games.

Can anyone help me revert back the video card driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start in safe graphical mode:

To start Ubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode) hold down the <kbd>left Shift</kbd> key as the computer starts to boot. If holding the Shift key doesn't display the menu press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key repeatedly to display the GRUB 2 menu.  From there you can choose the recovery option.

[image]

Reference: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode)

Comment: Thank you.  Using this and other advice I was able to 'sudo apt-get remoev --purge nvidia*'  It seems I'm back to my original configuration