# 14.04 couldn't log in

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen

I couldn't log in to my user account. When I tried it the screen returned to the log in screen. I am able to log in using ctrol alt f1 or an new created account, but not my own. Also rm /.Xautority doent work. Could someone type some log files the error could be in?

Comment: In recovery mode he said that the filesystem is "read only" or something

Answer (score 0):

You can try start system in recovery mode:

[How can I start in safe mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode)

Also, if you don`t mind , you might install gnome-session , for example:

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

and change session to login

Comment: after choosing cario-dock filling my password and pressing enter my ubuntu waited in a screen witch hasn't the log in field or anything. the only thing I could do was moving the mouse and switching to another tty.

Comment: @keesbroeksma Have you tried start system in safe mode ? It usually say it is read only , but once you are able to log in there are another options to try to solve regular log in .

Comment: I've start my system in safe mode. What are some startupscripts which could couse the problem?