# How to boot into recovery mode on Ubuntu on chromebook

Tags: 12.04, chromebook, password-recovery, recovery-mode

When I set up Ubuntu on my HP Chromebook 14 again after breaking it, I forgot that the admin password had to be 4 digits and set it as 1 (the password was just 1) since I don't really need a password on it. Anyway, so it set it to some random 5 digit and I can't do anything with software center, so how do I get to recovery mode?

Thanks in advance,

Kevin.

Edit: Ignore the stuff about the password needing to be 5 digits, I'm stupid, it just shows that in the user details. Still, how do you access recovery mode?

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode) or [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good step-by-step to get into recovery mode:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

then from the terminal, type in the following to change your password:

`passwd username`

where **username** is your username.

Comment: You can't do this on chromebook.

Comment: Going to have to change it then from the USB media.  Same set of instructions but boot from USB instead.  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/

Comment: @KevinBrown Have you tried holding down the left shift key at startup to get you to the grub menu?