# Problems running Ubuntu

Tags: boot, versions

When I try to boot in Ubuntu I get an error, to run it I try the Advanced options and I run it on a previous version. I guess it happened from something I installed and it crashed. How can I solve it?

Comment: What is Ubuntu version, what is kernel version? I guess it is 3.13.0-59.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it in [protected mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode) and repair with: `apt-get update --fix-missing`

Comment: How can i run it in protected mode? I already reinstalled everything, but i would like to know, and the error i was getting was some kind of cant acces tty or something like that.

Comment: i edited my post, theres a link to _how to get in the Protected Mode_
hopefully this helps you :)