# Noveau driver unstable, causes computer freeze

Tags: drivers, 16.04, crash

After an update, the Nvidia drivers wrecked my machine, I tried all fixes I could but couldn't get it to work until I purged Nvidia and selected Noveau. However, my computer freezes randomly the monitor only shows diagonal broken lines. I can only restart it by pushing the power button. Any way of fixing this would be much appreciated.

[image: this is what happens]

After completing step 1 , I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` from Terminal, where I got a [bunch of errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23573811/). Of course, I have no clue whatsoever about their meaning.

So, from Terminal (normal boot) I ran `$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` and got a [message saying I needed to downgrade](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23580925/). I used `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` to downgrade and [got an error saying it can't be done](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23589999/).

I continued with step 2, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` with no errors. However after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I got a [list of errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23590683/) about not being able to fetch certain files. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 nvidia-settings` was error-free.

Method 1 did not work at all, I got stuck an the login loop.

After trying method 2 (manually purging, then installing only the 304 driver) had the same result: login loop.

However, when purging again from TTY (the only way to get access after installing nvidia) I got a message that caught my attention: it said it was removing nvidia settings 375 **which I did not install**. Could this be a clue?

[image]

Text (right side is cut off on some lines):

```
INFO:Disable nvidia-304
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_he…
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Purging configuration files for nvidia-304 (304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ..…
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.132-0ubuntu0.1…
 ...
Removing nvidia-settings (375.20-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-settings (375.20-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04…
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ..…
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
alfredo@a-s56021a:~$
```

After having access, I manually purged Nvidia from terminal, with [this output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23591548/). Seems to me it doesn't matter if I install **only** 304, a bunch of other stuff comes with it. Could this be the problem?

Why is it so complicated? The only issue I've had with Ubuntu in 6 years, is with the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: [boot in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode#) & install the old Nvidia drivers that worked

Comment: @Vencen the old Nvidia driver I was using (304.132 legacy) didn't work at all. I have Noveau selected in "additional drivers" and that is the only way I could avoid the login loop, If i choose Nvidia 304 I get either flickering black screen or login loop.

Comment: @Vencen thanks for the edit, it is quite clear now, however I ran into a problem, added screenshots

Comment: @Vencen got more error messages, don't know if I should carry on with step 2...

Comment: @Vencen as per your instruction: found error. Stopped.

Comment: @Vencen I installed PPA-Purge, but when trying to remove the old PPA I got `$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: ubuntu-x-swat x-updates
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ubuntu-x-swat x-updates`

Comment: @Vencen when attempting downgrade got error message. Do I continue with step 2 anyway?

Comment: @Vencen back to square one, I regret to inform...

Answer (score 1):

## -if you can't boot normally or login successfully

- boot why  holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key or repeatedly pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> until you see the [GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode) menu
select `advanced options`
 then `recovery mode` 
 wait.
 select `resume normal boot`
 then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> 

  your'll be using the fail safe graphics drivers

[More black screen help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

## - collect infomation

-
In a terminal run

> **$** lspci -k | grep -EA2 'GA|3D' && dpkg -l | grep nvidia

Save the output to a text document

## -Step 1

-
Resetting the system to the default open source drivers.

**Manually** purge all previously installed  proprietary Nvidia drivers with this command

> **$** sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nvidia-* libcuda-*

This is mandatory if they where previously installed & has be done every time when switching proprietary drivers .   ‍

**Reboot**     ‍      ‍      ‍

## -**step 2**

-
[Installing the latest  proprietary  Nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

> **$** sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
>
> **$** sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Automatically install the recommended driver like the  "additional drivers" system would

> **$** ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

**Done !**

**Reboot** x2 all for changes to take affect

Then install nvidia-settings & reconfigure the Xorg servers settings

> **$** sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings && sudo nvidia-xconfig -v

## troubleshooting

-
Try rebooting again, some times  configuration files are missing or corrupted  & need to be created, 
 rebooting allows the new configuration to take place.

If the problem persists (installing the latest driver did not work) 

do **step  1**  again.
then continue to installation **Method 1** or **Method 2**

In you saved text document find. 
`ii  nvidia-(you numbers here)` make a note of those numbers

**Method 1: Downgrading**

Downgrade the driver. I.E. UnUpdate it.

Use the links for tutorials on how to downgrade

[downgrade with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)    ‍     &  ‍      [downgrade Graphically](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/)

Last command should look something like

> **$** sudo apt-get install nvidia-340=340.98-0ubuntu0

**Reboot** for changes to take affect

Selecting the recommended Nvidia driver in "additional drivers" afterwards 
 will change the version & can cause problems

**Method 2: manual choice**

Manually choose an (older) driver version
[check for driver versions that support you GPU](https://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html)
You can generate a list using-

simple list

> **$** apt-cache search '^nvidia-[:digit]' --names-only

complete list

> **$** apt-cache search '^nvidia-*'

**install your Chosen version**

> **$** sudo apt-get install nvidia-<kbd>(**your chosen version  number**)</kbd> nvidia-settings

Note. no <kbd>(</kbd>brackets<kbd>)</kbd>

Then **Reboot** x2 for changes to take final affect

`nvidia-settings` is universal to all driver versions

The latest version of `nvidia settings` is 375. thats why it's installed, 
if the the new `nvidia-settings` is a problem don't install it,    it just configures the graphics settings.

If it works ok then install `nvidia-settings` & reconfigure the Xorg servers settings

> **$** sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings && sudo nvidia-xconfig -v

## -Other

-
**When** you find a stable driver run this command. then you will never have this problem again.

> **$** sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-<kbd>(**your version  number**)</kbd>

That way upgrading the system won't update the Nvidia driver.

[Help on package holding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

So [complicated](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2911459/why-nvidia-graphics-cards-are-the-worst-for-open-source-but-the-best-for-linux-gaming.html) ? you're not the only  [One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757080/why-is-it-so-hard-to-install-nvidia-drivers-what-is-the-most-fool-proof-method).

## -information

- 
Physical graphics card information & current GPU driver in use
  ‍      ‍     ‍      ‍

> **$** lspci -k | grep -EA2 'GA|3D' && dpkg -l | grep nvidia
>
> **$** ubuntu-drivers devices

Nvidia GPU's get legacy support  after 10 years

ii **=** installed, nouveau **=** open source, nvidia **=** proprietary.

> Google a lot & don't give up :)

Comment: Last time I did that, was when everything broke down. But, I'll give it a shot and post back. Do I need to select Nvidia in "additional drivers" afterwards? Thanks.

Comment: The additional drivers system is "smart" but not all knowing.

Comment: here's the output: 'lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
 Kernel driver in use: nouveau'

Comment: any pointers, sir?

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand your solution

Comment: -1 Bad formatting/Markdown; way too many revisions (48 at the moment). I tried to edit this but gave up at the second paragraph inside an invalid HTML tag. Please revise this answer to make it more professional: 1) Label the sections. 2) If you need to edit to add more info, label the edit. 3) Use four spaces at the start of a line for code formatting.

Comment: @Vencen after `$ apt-cache showpkg nvidia-304 | grep 304.117-` there were no results. I ran `$ apt-cache showpkg nvidia-304` and got this results, http://paste.ubuntu.com/23631385/ with no  result like 304.117-0ubuntu1.

Comment: @Vencen do I try with 304.132?

Comment: @Vencen I did and tested for a couple of days. Everything is fixed now. I will edit my question accordingly and give you the "answered" thing after. Thanks for your assistance.