# There isn't any "recovery mode" line on the GRUB menu using my USB drive with Kubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, recovery-mode

I'm very, very happy using my new USB drive with Kubuntu 18.04 and persistent storage, but I have this challenge. I've read the documentation linked below but there isn't any "recovery mode" line on the GRUB menu.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

[How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)

[How can I start Ubuntu in Safe Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode)

Holding the Shift key doesn't display the menu. If I press the Esc key repeatedly, the GRUB 2 menu isn't displayed but the GRUB command-line appears instead, so I can't start Kubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode).

Also, I want to say that English isn't my mother tonge.

Thank you very much for your help. The Ubuntu Community is amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live sessions with or without persistence do not have recovery mode (and it wouldn't make sense if they did).

It's not the same as an installed system.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice day [week, month, year, life, etc]!

Comment: Users can assure notification with @username (not necessary in our own questions/answers) but this isn't exactly PMs.

Comment: I could've replied in Spanish if I were at my laptop but because I'm with an Android tablet with only English and Galician-Portuguese installed, the autocorrect makes an hell out of trying to write in any other language.

Comment: Logo respondo en galego para engadir variedade :) @GabrielaGarcia, me sorprenden positivamente as tuas a aportacións:  800 1 4 14. ¡Grazas! E espero que todo vaia ben