# Ubuntu 18.04 Boot Loop

Tags: boot

(Disclaimer: Newbie to Linux and Ubuntu)

- Installed Update via Ubuntu Updater
- Also changed the ubuntu.css file to change the login background
- Restarted the system

Now it boots up shows the fsck "clean.... " message (as usual)
-> shows cursor on blank screen and goes back to the fsck message
-> i can't even change to terminal via CTRL+F2,F3,.... it just goes back to this message (it shows the login for 5 ms then goes back)

I don't think the change to the ubuntu.css file created this problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Best way to see if it's the .css file is to undo what you did.  When the machine starts to boot hit the esc button or the hold down the shift key to reveal the grub boot menu, then select recovery It will take you to a screen where you can select root terminal.  from there you can open the .css file and revert your changes you'll have to use nano text editor or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... i have to mention i cant even go to a terminal by hitting CTRL+F2 ... it just goes back to the fsck message

Comment: ctrl+Alt+F2 F3 etc have you tried?

Comment: Yes i did. It shows the terminal for like 5 ms then goes back.

Comment: seems ubuntu.css is the problem.. do you have live usb?

Comment: yes i do ... should i revert the changes or something else ?

Comment: Ok.. log on with live USB. if your / partition is `/dev/sdX` first run `sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt` then open `/mnt/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` delete all the content in it and then copy paste all the content in `/mnt/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` in `ubuntu.css` file and reboot..

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything works fine.

Comment: Ok.. now from ubuntu packages.. get the original file ubuntu.css and replace the contents when ever you like.. remember you need to delete the content and copy paste.. never delete the original file and never rename it.. this applies to shell theme files in this case..

Comment: you need to get into recovery mode here's a link that tells you how to do that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode  once there you will be presented with a menu select root terminal. From there you can open .css file with nano text editor and fix the problem. The other way is to use the live usb and boot to the live desktop and navigate to the file from there and fix it.  Next time you change a file like that always back up the old file first so it can be easily returned to original if need be. Good luck. You can also do a clean install if you want.