# VM BOX won't load due of missing file

Tags: upgrade, updates, virtualbox

I have a small problem while loading up Ubuntu from a VM BOX.

I have used it for a few months without problems as I used it mainly for embedded school projects. Now I have a problem.

I did: `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update and upgrade the system. However, now when I try to load it up, this happens. [Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNc2z.png)

When that loads up and I press OK, nothing happens then. It is basically crashing.
What might be the issue here?

Comment: The issue is that a critical system file seems to be missing. Boot into [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode) and use apt to reinstall the `base-files` package: `sudo apt install --reinstall base-files`. If there are any errors in the output (especially errors that you do not understand), then take a picture of the complete output so we can see all errors, and the sequence in which they occur.

Comment: Hey.

Thank you so much. Which menu option should I pick?
Clean,
DPKG,
fsck,
grub,
network,
root
or system-summery.

Also, I've tried root and it end up telling me that access to the console/root account is locked.

Comment: I'm sorry. My bad.

[link](https://imgur.com/gallery/iCWy9Zv)
This is the menu I get up when I set it up in recovery mode.

Comment: Try 'resume' or 'dkpg'. Some of the others would work, too.

Comment: Hmmm. I tried them both and I get the same problem as I did first.