# Cannot get to Ubuntu recovery mode (or Grub menu)

Tags: recovery-mode

I know there are lots of questions re this, but none solve my exact issue.

I accidentally gave a usermod -G instead of -a -G, and so have been removed from sudoers.  I am using BIOS, so most of the threads talking about holding shift to get into recovery mode don't work.  ESC brings me to a grub command line, but cannot get anything useful out of that.  The closest similar question I found (I can't find it again) had the same issue, but his was resolved by typing `normal` and then it worked.  When I type `normal`, all I get is that it reboots but then ESC no longer works to even get me into the GRUB menu until the next time I reboot.

Ubuntu 20.
TIA

Edit: Despite this being marked as a dup, it is VERY CLEARLY NOT because I reference all of the normal directions, and explain how it's not working.  Not only that, but I did end up resolving it, and it goes against all of the documentation, thereby making it novel, and likely useful for others.  Typical Stack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I start Ubuntu in Safe Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode) If not, then i suppose you will be re-installing.

Comment: It didn't quite, because that article, along with the others I saw say to repeatedly press ESC, and that was wrong, at least in my case.  I pressed it exactly one time, and boom, brought me to the recovery screen I needed.
Thanks for the help

Comment: According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/): *With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the Esc key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen.* This was one of the answers to "How to start Ubuntu in Console mode" even though danny2327 claimed *Despite this being marked as a dup, it is VERY CLEARLY NOT*.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it.  All of the articles I saw say to repeatedly press ESC, and that was wrong, at least in my case. I pressed it exactly one time, and waited a few seconds, and that brought me to the recovery screen I needed where I could resolve the other issues.