# How to fix sudo after “chmod -R 777 /etc/”?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, ssh, sudo, root

I have been looking around on how to solve the issue of changing the permissions on the directory where the `sudoers` file is located (in my case `/etc/`).

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127446/how-to-fix-sudo-after-chmod-r-777-usr-bin) points to the same problem, however the solution isn't feasible because you still need sudo priviliges which are not accessible.

However, if there were a way to access the session with root privileges, could I run `chmod -R ugo+r /etc/` and get things back to normal? How can I login from a SSH (I'm using PuTTY), and get this back to normal?

I cannot currently reboot in safe mode, since it is a cloud server from a client and its out of my reach. It's an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine, and I could try to ask for the root credentials, although I have been reading that there are none (so I have no clue how to do 'login' as root...)

EDIT: Now I can't even connect with PuTTY... Please help!

EDIT2: after following the advice provided, here is the `pkexec` authentication error after typing the correct password

```
soporteit@redacted:~$ pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/chmod' as the super user
Authenticating as: Soporte IT,,, (soporteit)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
soporteit@redacted:~$
```

EDIT2: so far it has been impossible to do this action from the shell. The machine keeps blocking our actions, and after the previous authentication error, it blocks our IP. Going to try to reboot the virtual machine using [this tutorial](http://kb.parallels.com/en/123324) and enter `root` mode to modify the file permissions

Comment: Sorry, this comment is not really helpful, but if you have cared to set up a password for root, then use it. If not: I'm very curious for answers that are not short of: transplant the disk to another box and change the settings.

Comment: I am trying to figure that out as well. But now PuTTY keeps giving me fatal connection errors! I have no clue why this is happening

Comment: Can you ping the box?

Comment: Why does the solution in the linked question not work for you?  It requires `pkexec`, not `sudo`.  `pkexec` in the default ubuntu configuration requires the user to be a member of the `sudo` group, but not that there be a valid `sudoers`.

Comment: @GyroGearloose yes I can ping the box from cmd, but PuTTY cannot establish a connection to port 22...

Comment: @user4556274 it does work, but then its asked me for credentials, I typed in the password (made sure about caps etc) and it denied authentication

Comment: @user4556274 I have edited the question to show a screenshot of what happens when i run pkexec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP answering. So I got as far as rebooting in safe mode the Ubuntu Virtual Machine (the System Admin had to).

From there, we executed `mount -o ro,remount /`

Got to this from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode) and changing the `-o rw` part to `-o ro`

Answer (score 1):

With this 2 commands:

```
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers 
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

*Y need to recheck my Terminal history to confirm, because I have same problem past week.*

OK, checked I do also:

```
pkexec chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: I have attached pictures of how it fails to do this operation

Comment: Now, I see the snapshot. This works for me, but without `root` user you must be able at least to use `pkexec` or `su root`
About the PuTTY lock, maybe the errors blacklisted your IP, try to access from a different Internet access and different computer.

Comment: I will try this asap. In the meantime, is there any way to restart the Ubuntu server in secure mode **from the ssh**? I have read that from this mode you can access with root privileges

Comment: I don't know if you can enter secure mode without *physical access* to the computer.