# accidently blocked access to sudoers.d whilst trying to change ushare config

Tags: sudo, root

Basically was trying to change the ushare config and needed permissions for some reason so, I changed with `sudo -i` and in the process did somthing and now I can't access superuser to change any of the permissions.

Also it says `/etc/sudoers` is mode 0660, but should be 0440 in the Terminal when I try and access it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You've changed the permissions of one or more of `sudo`'s configuration files. Because the files could potentially lead to major insecurity on some systems with the wrong permissions, `sudo` refuses to work at all unless their permissions are set correctly. Since `sudo` will not work, you cannot use it to become `root` (the superuser) to fix them.

However, there are actually two mechanisms used on a desktop Ubuntu system to perform actions as `root`: `sudo`, and [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html). PolicyKit provides a command that you can use to run run non-graphical programs as `root`, similar to sudo: the [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) command.

If your problem is that the file `/etc/sudoers` has the wrong permissions, you can fix this with:

```
pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

Then you should be able to use `sudo` again. (You can try running a harmless command like `sudo ls` to find out.)

If there are files in `/etc/sudoers.d` that have the wrong permissions, you may have to set their permissions correctly, in a similar manner. Or just do it for all of them at once:

```
pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/*
```

(Even the `README` file in there is required to have these restrictive permissions, so there should be no problem using that command. However, you likely don't need it, if it's just `/etc/sudoers` itself that got the wrong permissions.)

See also [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-anderror-and-not-allowi).

---

You might have been tempted to change the permissions of `/etc/sudoers` or of a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` to edit it. You should not do this, and you do not need to. **In the future, you should use [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) to edit these files instead.** That does so safely, and prevents the problem you are now experiencing.

Comment: @Alec If this worked for you, you should consider [marking it as the accepted answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer).