# How can I fix broken sudo - sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 23?

Tags: sudo

I am getting this error:

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 23
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I was trying to disable password authentication so I don't have to type password every time I want to install something, but I probably changed it in a not very good way.
I am a newbie to Ubuntu, I got sick of Windows :)

So far I've found some people suggesting booting in single user mode, but I'm afraid of messing things up more.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: If you boot in single user mode and use `visudo`, then it won't let you save an incorrect file, so you will not  be able to mess things up further.

Comment: Thank you, how do I change the file, then? And, how exactly do I boot in single user mode?

Comment: Hold Shift immediately while booting so that you get the GRUB screen. Select the recovery mode. Choose to drop to a root terminal. Run `mount -n -o remount,rw /` and then `visudo`. Ctrl+O saves, Ctrl+X exits without saving. It won't let you save a bad file.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ it would be nice to convert the comment to answer and let the questioner to mark it as the best answer. For future - help - others I mean.

Comment: Deactivating that password switch is about as bad as deactivating UAC on Windows. Every command that tries so call `sudo` internally can do without any problems. You could easily have some software (rootkit) installed without you knowing. I would *strongly* discourage doing this in the first place.

Comment: I know, I know, it was a huge mistake. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Comment: @psusi and close voters: huh? It's a question, with proper answers. It's just missing a "how can I fix this error" sentence, which I've just added. There's no need to close it.

Comment: @Alaa, it says this is what happened, and this is what I have already been told to do to fix it.  That's not a question.

Comment: @psusi when problems are questions? He is asking how to revert it back, and is giving us the history of his actions, he describe his problems, he got [a solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/209558/how-can-i-fix-broken-sudo-sudo-parse-error-in-etc-sudoers-near-line-23#comment260240_209558). Why close it?

Comment: @Braiam, because the "solution" is *in* the "question".  Without knowing why that isn't acceptable ( besides "I'm afraid" ) it isn't possible to provide a real answer.

Comment: On newer Ubuntu distributions, there's a simple solution (not requiring any reboot nor recovery), described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/73872

Comment: Isn't there already an answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi actually. Just type `pkexec visudo`

Answer (score 62):

Fixing this is dead simple, and it is answered [elsewhere on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi).

Short answer, use:

```
pkexec editor_of_choice
```

Comment: This is definitely the simplest and best answer. I had no clue pkexec existed. Thanks a lot  both

Comment: When I do pkexec, it gives list of users to authenticate. When I type password, it gives Authentication failure. Please help.

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka I ran into this also. [This solution on GitHub](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012#issuecomment-335350903) saved me and about a hundred other people.

Comment: This didnt work for me with an error " No session for cookie " but I did this in two terminals: 
In the first terminal run the following command to get its PID.

echo $$

In the second terminal run

pkttyagent --process PID_FROM_STEP_1

Then you can run "sudo pico /etc/sudoers" or whatever you want in first terminal, and the second terminal will ask for user password. and will work

Comment:  thx, useful compare to reboot in recovery mode red-tape procedures... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195402/3806250 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58199760/3806250

Comment: Using pkexec directly didn't work for me (didn't accept password), but strangely enough @Shyamkkhadka solution using 2 terminals worked!

Answer (score 19):

Hold Shift immediately while booting so that you get the GRUB screen. Select the recovery mode. Choose to drop to a root terminal. Run `mount -n -o remount,rw /` and then `visudo`. It'll let you fix your problems with the file and save. It won't let you save a malformed file.

Comment: Shift didn't work for me, I had be pressing keys to get grub

Comment: @nafg Every configuration is different.

Comment: I don't have visudo installed in my ubuntu. What can I do ?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, "Drop to Root terminal" asks for root password (which obviously will not work, because /etc/sudoers is broken). Pressing Ctrl+D will just bring you back to the GRUB screen.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm glad I know about dropping to a root terminal now, that's very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Folowing solution is for remote servers, it works!

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036382&p=12144840#post12144840

then just use visudo to add *wheel*, etc

---

1. Rename your current file

   `mv /etc/sudoers{,.bak}`
2. Create a new one `vi /etc/sudoers` with the following basic content:

   ```
   # /etc/sudoers
   #
   # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
   #
   # See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
   # Defaults    env_reset
   # Host alias specification
   # User alias specification
   # Cmnd alias specification
   # User privilege specification
   root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
   # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command after they have
   # provided their password
   # (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
   # it further down)
   %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
   #
   #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
   # Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
   %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
   ```
3. Run `visudo` and add your custom stuff.

Comment: how to move it without sudo and sudo is broken?

Comment: @Ewoks   use 'su' , but you have to know the super user password

Answer (score 2):

If u messed up your sudoers file.You'll need to:

- Reboot into recovery mode (hit escape during boot, choose the recovery mode option on the grub screen)
- Choose the 'Enable networking' option (if you don't your filesystem will be mounted as read-only. who knew)
- Chosee the 'Drop to root shell' option
- run visudo, fix your file
- Reboot with normal grub option

source :- http://mario.net.au/content/recover-etcsudoers-ubuntu-1204

Comment: Follow up question: When I choose the `Enable networking` option, I'm prompted to tell the system that I'm sure. I do that and I just drop into nothing. No root prompt, nothing. What should I expect to see/do after the 2nd step? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

Create a copy

```
cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.bak
```

Edit problem parts there

```
vim /etc/sudoers.bak
```

Replace the origin sudoers file

```
cp /etc/sudoers.bak /etc/sudoers
```

It works for me.

Comment: It worked when i logged in using super user (su -) and executed above steps.. Thanks

Comment: But you need to be root. so...

Answer (score 1):

I screwed up the sudoers file to find out that I don't remember the root password. Solution: rebooted under Windows (I have a dual boot) and edited the file using ext2fsd (you have to reboot after the installation). In principle, this could be another Linux or a live flash, not necessarily Windows.

Comment: A lot of people dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu, so this is a solid approach! I know been a while since you've posted this answer... but might you be willing to [edit] this to expand it with detailed information about specifically how to set up and use ext2fsd for this purpose?