# Want to execute sudo command on shell startup

Tags: sudo, bashrc

I've put a command `sudo do something` in my `~/.bashrc`, this works but everytime I open the terminal I have to type in my password. How do I make it so there is no password-typing?

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `NOPASSWD` attribute in the sudoers file to tell sudo not to require a password. A line like the follows in the sudoers file should let you run that command without a password:

`yourlogin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: command_here`

To edit the sudoers file, run the command `sudo visudo`.

Comment: This operation is too risky.

Comment: That depends on the command run. I assume user19192 actually knows what he's doing and wants to run this :)

Comment: @Hckr I think there's no risk if you have control over **your** script.

Comment: Yes, @EvandroSilva . I thought that this operation allows all scripts to be opened as root without password.Cos, I have just seen "command_here".Sorry.

Comment: yeah, `NOPASSWD: ALL` is a different beast. Wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: WARNING: Do not use a regular text editor to edit the `sudoers` file, always use the `visudo` command. Because if you mess it up and save it like that, you won't be able to use `sudo` afterwards: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-an-error-and-its-not-allo

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the sudoers file by executing the following line:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

add the following line to the file: `your_login ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: command`

Comment: NOTE: I generally don't encourage this option because the sudo function is built in to protect the user. no longer requiring a password is negating the purpose of it. However if you are confident it will not be a security problem then go ahead.

Comment: Using gedit to edit /etc/sudoers is a recipe for disaster. If you make a typo in the sudoers file you can lock yourself out of sudoing.  Always use `visudo` to edit: `export EDITOR=gedit; sudo -E visudo`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the sudoers file with the command sudo visudo.

As seen here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt?newreg=fb648518a0b0446e92cb2a685755daca

Your command that you want to authorize should be the path to it or you will get an error.

```
yourlogin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/command_here
```