# How often is the password asked for sudo commands? Where can I set it up?

Tags: sudo

I execute quite a lot of `sudo` commands.

I noticed that if I execute one and then another one within few minutes, the 2nd time I don't get the message:

> [sudo] password for my_username:

but I do get it when there is more time between the execution of the two commands.

What's the period of time in which the message is not appearing? How can we check it / update it?

Comment: sudo visudo, then %sudo line should be %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL)NOPASSWD: ALL , it will not ask you any password when you type sudo any-stuff

Comment: This (NOPASSWD:ALL) is a very dangerous suggestion. It will make your installation unsecured.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The default timeout of `sudo` is 15 minutes; that is, `sudo` will remember your password for 15 minutes by default.

You can modify this default timeout by adding a string in the file `/etc/sudoers`. However, you don't modify the file directly, but instead you use the command `sudo visudo`.

So, type `sudo visudo` in a terminal. This will open up the (actually, a temporary) file for us to edit, using your preferred editor.

> **Note:** if you are using `visudo` for the first time, you should be asked which editor you would like to use, so choose your editor. There's no "better" editor, but I prefer `nano`. If you've already used `visudo` and chose an editor before, but you want to use another editor for the time being, you can do `sudo EDITOR=vi visudo` to use `vi`, or change it to `nano` to use `nano`. If you want to permanently change your preferred editor, do `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`.

Look for this line:

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

And add `timestamp_timeout=X` (with a comma) at the end of it, where **X** is the time you want to set in minutes.

So your line should look like this, as an example:

```
Defaults    env_reset,timestamp_timeout=5
```

If you specify 0, you will always be asked the password. If you specify a negative value, the timeout will never expire.

Once done, save and exit.

**Source: [RootSudoTimeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout)**

Comment: Thank you, @Alaa, it is a good and helpful answer. Just as a side note, the `Ctrl + x` part is not always matched as the editor can be for example `vi` (in my case).

Comment: By the way, I did a big mistake adding a new line with only `Default timestamp-0` instead of the one with `env_reset`. It broke my sudoers file. Had to use http://askubuntu.com/a/73872/143251 to solve it!

Comment: @fedorqui: That is exactly why you should use visudo (as Alaa recommends) instead of editing the file directly. The former will syntax check the file for you, preventing you from locking yourself out of sudo.

Comment: Yes, yes, that's what I did @Plutor . But `vi` is the editor I have defined for `visudo`. The problem is that I saved the file although I got a warning message when closing it. My fault, obviously.

Comment: @fedorqui, yeah I sort of wanted to remove that part because anyone could be using a different editor. I've edited my answer to not be editor specific.

Answer (score 5):

See this post here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=116697#post116697

Edit `/etc/sudoers` file, use `sudo visudo` command for safety. Add `timestamp_timeout=0` to the line starting `Defaults` to ask everytime, or positive X for X minute delay.

Comment: I have to register in the forum to see it. In the meanwhile, could you kindly indicate which file should I edit with `timestamp_timeout=0` line?

Comment: OK, fixed answer.

Comment: It did the trick! I will accept the other answer as it has a more comprehensive explanation and includes the `env_reset` reference, which is important. Anyway this your answer was also very helpful, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this expires or not, but you could try

```
sudo su
```

It will ask you for the password and after that all commands are run as sudo.

Comment: Yes, @Rat2000, but I want to keep using my user and not `root`. I think it is safer. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Comment: sudo su makes you become root. Your prompt should then be root@yourpc. Mind that root has it's own .bashrc, so your aliases won't work. Mind also that root can do severe damage to the system, so be careful!