# How to change the timeout between sudo sessions?

Tags: sudo, timeout

What is the default timeout interval of a sudo session? How to edit that?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/309202/how-often-is-the-password-asked-for-sudo-commands-where-can-i-set-it-up