# A noob question about sudo -s

Tags: command-line, 16.04, sudo, password

So when I do sudo -s in my terminal I get into root mode, and after I do whatever I wanted to do, I do 'exit'.
Now If I do 'sudo -s' again, the terminal does not ask for any password and enters root mode directly.
Is this a normal behavior? I use ubuntu 16.04.

as I remember this was not the case 3-4 days ago,I think something has changed today,cant figure out what.

If this is not normal, how do i rectify it.

Comment: See [How often is the password asked for sudo commands? Where can I set it up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309202/how-often-is-the-password-asked-for-sudo-commands-where-can-i-set-it-up)