# Timeout for password input for user login

Tags: login, password, users

is it possible to set a timeout for ubuntu to ask the user for his login password. Let me give you an example. I put my laptop to sleep and after 2.5 seconds I think 'ah f**k, I forgot something'. So I reopen my laptop and he asks me for my password. Is it possible to set a timeout for like 30 seconds?

Comment: are you referring to the [sudo timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309202/how-often-is-the-password-asked-for-sudo-commands-where-can-i-set-it-up)?

Comment: No, I'm referring to, `close the laptop. Open it up right away, then entering password - timeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as how long you have to wait after closing your machine, I'm not aware of any value you can change for that. It's technically considered logging out which always requires a password to get back in. You can disable the password requirement completely by following the instructions in this link [Disable password login requirement](https://itstillworks.com/disable-password-authentication-ubuntu-8289431.html)

Dont think this what you meant, but to set the timeout for how often you need to enter your sudo password from the last time you entered it, here is a link with instructions [Change sudo password timeout][1] [1]: https://itsfoss.com/change-sudo-password-timeout-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess it is not possible then :)