# Repeated unnecessary password prompts

Tags: password, prompt

[image: Prompt]
My Ubuntu 18.04 desktop keeps throwing up keyring password prompts that are clearly unnecessary, since I can just cancel them and continue working without trouble.  This happens immediately after I login and continues throughout my session, whenever I start Chrome or Remmina or several other applications.

Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201511/ubuntu-asking-for-password-again-and-again) I can temporarily stop this happening by removing or renaming .Xauthority and logging out and in again, but that's a hassle and I'd like to automate it somehow.

Any ideas or other helpful comments? I don't want to stop all password prompts, just the unnecessary ones.

This happens immediately after login and when I open certain applications, eg Chrome or Remmina, from a launcher (Terminal and sudo not involved).

Comment: Please verify you are not talking about the sudo timeout in terminal.  If so, see this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/309202/how-often-is-the-password-asked-for-sudo-commands-where-can-i-set-it-up.  When you say it "continues sporadically" -- what steps do you need to take to reproduce the prompt?  Do you get a password prompt even when the PC is idle and you aren't using it?  It would also help if you would provide a screenshot of the password prompt you are getting.  The more relevant context you can provide the better.

Comment: Outside of `sudo` issue Nmath already asked about, the only experience I've had close to this is with the chromium browser (if at first run I didn't provide the password to unlock keyring).  Closing the browser and re-opening was my temporary fix it for me (I forget how I resolved permanently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue isn't about using sudo in a terminal. It happens immediately Ubuntu starts and then occasionally thereafter.

I "solved" this problem by reinstalling Ubuntu. I still have the original 18.04 installation (dual-booting) and it still happens on that instance, but now I understand that it has something to do with my flatmate's Chrome instance. I use Firefox and don't have the issue. On the new 20.04 installation it only happens when Chrome is started.