# Accidentally deleted 'sudo'

Tags: sudo, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted the `/usr/bin/sudo` file. How can I restore it?

I have found [a thread on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1682672), but it seems to be not solved.

Comment: you are a god amongst men

Comment: Related: [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason I write this instruction here is that I didn't find a step-by-step solution when I ran into the problem myself. I'm a Linux newbie myself, so feel free to edit this :)

These steps solved the problem for me:

Boot into recovery mode (press **Esc** or left **Shift** after BIOS splash)
[image]

Select *Drop to root shell prompt* option
[image]

Mount the file system in writable mode:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Add the internet connection (I'm not sure if this works with Wi-Fi):

```
dhclient eth0
```

Now you have to purge the existing sudo package. It's protected against removal, so you have to set this environment variable:

```
export SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes
```

Purge the sudo:

```
apt-get purge sudo
```

That command also purged the ubuntu-minimal package, so if we run

```
apt-get install ubuntu-minimal
```

this will restore both packages

Reboot the system:

```
reboot
```