# How can I change the number of password entry attempts allowed by sudo?

Tags: sudo

By default, `sudo` prompts me to input my user password a maximum of three times if I input wrong password. How can I change it to unlimited times(?)? How can I make it so that it asks me for my password until I enter the right one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is documented in `man sudoers`. The setting you are looking for is:

```
 passwd_tries      The number of tries a user gets to enter his/her pass‐
                   word before sudo logs the failure and exits.  The
                   default is 3.
```

So, to change that to, for example, 5, run `sudo visudo` and add these lines:

```
## Allow a user to attempt to enter a password 5 times
Defaults        passwd_tries=5
```

As far as I know, there is no way to set it to unlimited times but you can simply use a huge number:

```
Defaults        passwd_tries=99999999
```

That is unlimited for all intents and purposes, unless you have a user with a *very* severe case of OCD, they won't attempt to enter a password more than 100 million times.

Comment: Now how can I change it to Unlimited times? (without large nubmer for `passwd_tries` )

Comment: @KasiyA set it to 99999999999 and live with it :)

Comment: oops I changed it to `passwd_tries=` and now I can not open again `sudo visudo` even I can not run any commands with sudo or gksu and gksudo ;(

Comment: @KasiyA umm, then you're in trouble. You need to either reboot into rescue mode and remove the line from the file or boot into a live session, mount your local drive and edit it there. This is why you should never play with these things unless you know what you're doing and have an open root session that will allow you to fix what you break.

Comment: The first instructions here detail how to get into recovery mode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: Also [This is exactly what I facing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi) @Seth

Comment: Ooh, I forgot all about that. Could be easier.

Comment: @Seth Yes I just used `pkexec visudo` and saved it again thanks it fixed.

Comment: @KasiyA never, ever, _ever_ edit `/etc/sudoers` directly. That's why I told you to use `visudo`. That would have protected you from this problem.

Comment: For the future: while using `visudo` should prevent the creation of a bad sudoers file, if you do create one that is bad or (more likely, with `visudo`) valid but nonfunctional, [the method detailed here with `pkexec` is usually sufficient to solve it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi), without even rebooting.

Comment: @terdon Recommend not going over 2 billion in case it's stored in a signed 32-bit integer. To what number your input would map depends on the implementation. Likely candidate is `1215752191`. Don't set it to `2^31-1` as this can cause trouble depending how the comparison with `passwd_tries` is implemented. At least go down to `2^31-2`.