# Error Using "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, sudo

I got the following error while using the `sudo apt-get update` command.

```
:~$sudo apt-get update
/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

[See here for the secreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U766.png)

I tried finding a solution, but I want a specific and precised answer. I am new to Ubuntu (14.04), please help me!

Comment: maybe duplicated here http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal

```
pkexec visudo
```

Change last line

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers
```

To

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

It should work.!

Comment: Thanks, but Its already  "#includedir /etc/sudoers.d" @Harshil

Answer (score 0):

Hold Shift immediately while booting it will open GRUB screen.Now select option  recovery mode. Choose to open root terminal. Run `mount -n -o remount,rw /` and then `visudo`.