# /etc/sudoers file corrupted and I can't run 'pkexec visudo' over SSH

Tags: 16.04, ssh, sudo, policykit, pkexec

Following the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/73864/569257) I get:

```
pkexec visudo

==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/sbin/visudo' as the super user
Authenticating as: Thomas,,, (tuc) Password:  polkit-agent-helper-1:
error response to PolicyKit daemon:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for
cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED === 
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

I am doing this via ssh since the box I am doing this on is used as a music server with no screen and is rather inaccessible.
This happened when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. I tried to copy a sudoers file from another recent 16.04 installation, but I can't do that because of the sudoers file:

```
sudo mv ~/gyrf sudoers

>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 36 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 37 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 38 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 39 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 40 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 41 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 42 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 43 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 44 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 45 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 46 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 47 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 48 <<<
>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 49 <<< 
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 36    
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Should I go get the box from the attic and try `pkexec visudo` or is something else wrong here?

Comment: AFAIK `pkexec` only allows this for a *local* user (not an SSH remote user) - so yes it should work from the attic

Comment: Either get the box, or get the drive, mount it in another computer and edit `sudoers` to suit. Depends on whats easiest.

Comment: @steeldriverIt It just worked to me as a remote user. JFYI.

Answer (score 83):

I ran into this problem also and with some digging, found a working solution. The original solution is from [this github issue for NixOS](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012) by EstalillaJ.

1. Open two ssh sessions to the target server.
2. In the first session, get the PID of bash by running:

   `echo $$`
3. In the second session, start the authentication agent with:

   `pkttyagent --process (pid from step 2)`
4. Back in the first session, run:

   `pkexec visudo`
5. In the second session, you will get the password prompt. visudo will start in the first session.

Comment: Holy shit dude, u saved my life! thx :D

Comment: that is crazy, it works perfect! and no need to reboot the system

Comment: Thanks a ton, this really saved me! ⭑

Comment: what if iam using non sudo user

Comment: In the second session, can't you enter simply `pkttyagent --process $$` instead of copying the process ID from the first session?

Comment: Saved my a** from rebooting a server into recovery, cheers a lot!

Comment: That is just remarkable dude! Wish I could favorite answers too!

Comment: I didn't understand why it worked, but it worked.

Comment: This saved my life, I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Man, I wish I'd found this answer before we took the server down to fix a bad sudoer file.

Comment: Thans a lot!! Your save my day!

Comment: This is a brilliant fix for those who screwed up `sudoers` file like me. Would be great if someone can explain it. It's great to know about `PolicyKit`. Thank you.

Comment: I'm super glad this is helping you all out. I was just as thrilled when I found that original answer! @Long, from my understanding pkexec is similar to sudo in allowing you to escalate to root permissions. Depending on the implementation it will look for a different group on the user (wheel, sudo, etc). Since the sudoers file is corrupt, sudo cannot check if the user has permissions to escalate privs. I think the two SSH sessions is just a quirk of how pkexec was designed. I mainly see it on Desktop Environments as the password prompt

Comment: I had given up finding a solution after I could not reboot, nor had physical access, neither succeeded with pkexec. But this worked out. Thanks a lot! (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: just saved my day ❤️

Comment: works for me! thanks

Answer (score 5):

My answer based on Satyen's

It was tested on Debian 10.4 **WITHOUT** ability to run visudo

1. Open two ssh sessions to the target server.
2. In the first session, get the PID of bash by running:

   `echo $$`
3. In the second session, start the authentication agent with:

   `pkttyagent --process (pid from step 2)`
4. Back in the first session, run:

   `pkexec su`
5. In the second session, you will get the password prompt. su will start in the first session.
6. Edit /etc/sudoers by (CTRL+S to save edits, CTRL+X to exit)

   `nano /etc/sudoers`