# Incorrectly created file in /etc/sudoers.d file with visudo, but broke things

Tags: sudo

I tried to do what I thought the comments in /etc/sudoers was telling me:

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
```

Then:

```
: ~ ; visudo --help
visudo - safely edit the sudoers file

usage: visudo [-chqsV] [-f sudoers] [-x file]
```

But I didn't read the bit after that more carefully, so I typed:

```
sudo visudo -x /etc/sudoers.d/dci
```

Instead of

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/dci
```

Now, I'm stuck. Any command I try to do with `sudo` gives me:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/dci: syntax error near line 1 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/dci: syntax error near line 1 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/dci: syntax error near line 2 <<<
…
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/dci: syntax error near line 58 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/dci near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

And without sudo, unsurprisingly:

```
: ~ ; rm /etc/sudoers.d/dci
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘/etc/sudoers.d/dci’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/sudoers.d/dci’: Permission denied
```

How do I fix this?

Update:

After trying the solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file), I got the following result:

```
: ~ ; pkexec visudo
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/sbin/visudo' as the super user
Authenticating as: DCi Admin,,, (dci)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

I was guessing this was because I was supposed to be using root password, but that's possibly a wrong guess.

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799669/etc-sudoers-file-corrupted-and-i-cant-run-pkexec-visudo-over-ssh) then fixed that problem.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, that's definitely a possible duplicate. I'm trying to get that answer working for me. Sadly, I don't (yet) have the password for root itself (nor physical access), just sudo access.

Comment: Just use your user password .

Comment: @MarkJ.Adams — that didn't work, but possibly I guessed incorrectly at the reason. I'll update my question with details.

Comment: There should be a button on your question that allows you to accept a suggested duplicate and close your question. Closing is better than deleting, as it can help people who would find your question on google etc. to get redirected to a solution.