# How do I edit an invalid sudoers file without root access?

Tags: permissions, sudo

How do I edit an invalid sudoers file?

I started looking at this question: [How to modify an invalid /etc/sudoers file? It throws an error and it's not allowing me to edit again to fix it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-an-error-and-its-not-allo)

But the voted answer assumes that I am allowed to run program as root using Policykit, which is unfortunately not the case.

Here is what happens:

```
$ sudo visudo

>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 29 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 29
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

What should I do? **I have no root access**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Switch on your computer.
- Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the Grub menu.
- Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.
- Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`
- Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.
- Select the option will be `Drop to root shell prompt`
- Run the commands

  ```
  mount -o remount,rw /
  mount --all
  visudo
  ```