# Unable to use any Sudo Commands when restarting, stopping, and starting Samba

Tags: server, sudo, samba

I recently made a samba server on an old laptop and that's all I wanted to do with it. About a day ago I was going to use vlc to look for the samba server (I was able to do so before) and couldn't find it. I tried restarting it and a sudo error popped up. Not only samba but other sudo commands as well do not work anymore. I uploaded a picture to see if it can help.

This is the exact problem:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Try this... Type `sudo -i` and then put in your root password. once you have done that then run `sudo service smbd restart` and see what they does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify an invalid /etc/sudoers file? It throws an error and it's not allowing me to edit again to fix it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-an-error-and-its-not-allo)