# >>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<< & based of my mistake in editing python file

Tags: permissions, python, sudo

I want to run pycharm as root by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530082/running-pycharm-as-root-from-launcher) instruction and [this](https://esmithy.net/2015/05/05/rundebug-as-root-in-pycharm/), but i have made mistake and don't added `:` in this script:
`user host = (root) NOPASSWD: full_path_to_python` in `/etc/sudoers.d/python` file.

So now I can not edit it anymore, by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file) instruction and more from internet like as you can see below ( also i have changed the admin user pass and forget previous pas , so now i can not use `su root` !):

```
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo gedit python
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ su so
Password: 
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo gedit
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ nano
Use "fg" to return to nano.

[3]+  Stopped                 nano
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo nano python
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo visudo -f python
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ su root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo -i  
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ 
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo bash
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo -s
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo apt-get update
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ 
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo apt-get update
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/python: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/python near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

my OS version is:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash/s$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone in python folder  and tried :

```
so@so-notebook:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo visudo -f python
```

As you can see at question, but i restated and tried :

`pkexec visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/python` 
From [here](https://www.edureka.co/community/37548/not-able-to-access-etc-sudoers-d-python-file),and add `:` in python scrip, so problem solved.