# Sorry, user xxxx is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on xxxx

Tags: sudo

I updated sudoers file with the following line

```
sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/docker
```

after save the changes, I can't run any sudo command and I can't edit sudoers file

I get the following error:

> Sorry, user xxxx is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on xxxx.

How to fix the issue ?

Comment: Try this first: [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/73872/178692)

Comment: Add the output of `id && sudo --list`. Did you edit with `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers`? You should avoid edit /etc/sudoers directly

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file/73872#73872 and its working,

Thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not using the visudo which refuses to allow a badly formed config file. Boot with an install disk and revert your changes by editing the file while the `/` partition on the drive is mounted in a `Terminal` session.