# I have succeeded in messing up /etc/sudoers and /etc/sudoers.d/sudoers. I can no longer access either of these files

Tags: sudo

entering sudo in a terminal session, I get the following response:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/sudoers: too many levels of includes near line 30 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/sudoers near line 30
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

When I first installed Ubuntu 20.04, I also removed the login requirement for entering a password on boot, having used other systems which did not have this requirement.

How can I recover from my errors and lack of understanding without re-installing Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Won't help you now, but this is exactly why you should never edit `sudoers` file directly, but always use `visudo`. I guess you can edit your `sudoers` using `pkexec visudo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/etc/sudoers.d/sudoers`  file.

Your `sudoers` file is  `/etc/sudoers`. This is configured to source files in  `/etc/sudoers.d/`. The file giving problems for you is `/etc/sudoers.d/sudoers`, which is normally not there. So I expect you will resolve the issue deleting that file.

Comment: I did finally succeed in removing /etc/sudoers.d/sudoers, and that seems to have fixed the problem. I believe my system is now operating in a normal fashion. Thank you!!