# I edited /etc/sudoers and now I cannot use sudo anymore

Tags: sudo, etc

I made the following change in the file /etc/sudoers:

```
sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And now I can't use sudo and can't edit /etc/sudoers anymore:

```
/etc/sudoers: near line syntax error 31 <<<
sudo: parsing error in /etc/sudoers near line 31
sudo: no valid sudoers source found; going out
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Is there a way to solve this problem or will I have to format my ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: If you can boot from a USB, you could mount the disk, find the 'bad' file and edit the line so that it reads correctly.  I would eliminate the new line, and in the future, I would use `sudo visudo ` to edit the file:  you can also do `sudo visudo -f /path/to/file` when fixing your current file.

Comment: The first error in the `/etc/sudoers` file becomes the EOF (end-of-file) marker; which is why the `visudo` command exists; ie. it will validate for errors & let you correct before exit if error(s) exist.   FYI:  yeah it's `visudo` but it will use whatever editor you've told it to, which may not be `vi`

Comment: If it's a desktop system, and you're logged in locally, you *may* be able to use `pkexec visudo`. See for example [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/73872/178692)

Comment: This problem is why one Always has a `root` shell open on another tetminal/ssh session when one is futzing with authentication stuff. This gives one a chance of recovery without booting from a Live USB.