# incorrectly edited the /etc/sudoers file and lost sudo priviledges

Tags: sudo

While trying to figure out why another user doesn't have sudo privileges I got rid of % in %sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL and after doing I myself cannot lost  sudo access. I get the message
"xxxx is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."
When I do su, I get "su: Authentication failure"
which means (based on googling) the root account is disabled.
Any ideas on how to fix this?  I also cannot run pkexec visudo as it says "Error executing command as another user: Not authorized". So any suggestions on how to fix this are appreciated. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 Unfortunately none of the solutions listed at
[How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file) worked for me

Many thanks

Comment: If you had a *root* account *enabled*, your chance will **not** have impacted that at all, ie. you can login as root & correct the issue. The root login is *disabled* however for on-topic Ubuntu systems by default (*don't forget there is a specific command to edit the sudoers files, that checks for errors before you exit; as any errors get treated as an end-of-file*)  You didn't provide release, so we're limited to being *generic* in replies.

Comment: The easiest fix I'd likely use is booting *live* media, manually navigating to the file & correcting from there.  You didn't specify if you're talking Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, but you can use whatever 22.04 media your machine is capable of booting & using.