# How can I get copies of default config files?

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Is there an easy way to get default configuration files of a given Ubuntu version? For example where to get the default `apache2.conf` for Ubuntu 9.10?

Comment: Related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternately you can download the appropriate .deb and extract the file.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Download the .deb and extract it with

```
ar p apache.deb data.tar.gz | tar zx
```

Then find the configuration file you need in the extracted directory.

I only mention this in the event you are running a server without X ;)

Comment: I'd recommend to download the deb file through `apt-get download <package>`

Answer (score 0):

Start from a live-CD, install apache2, and there you have them. Save them to an USB-stick, for instance, or to the cloud, attach them to an email for yourself.

Or save the current files, uninstall (purge) apache2, and reinstall it.