# Can't SSH localhost

Tags: ssh, localhost, hadoop

I can't SSH localhost. I have installed OpenSSH server as well on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32 bit).

connected to net (ip : 192.168.1.2)
installed hadoop, running hadoop for local machine.

Here's what I get :

```
root@kunal-Extensa-4620:/# ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "localhost" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: check if port 22 is open for incoming connections at your end

Comment: sudo ss -lnp | grep sshd # results in
LISTEN     0      128                      :::22                      :::*      users:(("sshd",556,4))
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*      users:(("sshd",556,3)) dear, its open and listening.

Comment: what is the exact message you get on scree when you do ssh user@localhost

Comment: What does the server log say on your connection attempt? See `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: what is the exact message you get on scree when you do ssh user@localhost you typed `ssh -vvv localhost` it doesnt makes any sense `ssh -vvv user@localhost` should be the thing

Comment: remove and reinstall OpenSSH not sure but this can fix this problem

Comment: Perhaps PermitRootLogin is set to false in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config?

Comment: sshd_config file is totally empty ? normal i guess not ? Y

Comment: When i do ssh user@localhost, i get the same message what i get earlier. the same log at terminal which i posted in my question. i have tried that once removing and reinstalling openssh, thanks

Comment: Though i wonder Y SSHD_CONFIG IS EMPTY ?? I opened it via gedit,and it came out complete blanks like a white sheet ?nothing written at all ?

Comment: Thanks all, i guess its running now. i removed, purged and reinstalled. here's the output :ssh localhost
root@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Fri Jun 14 17:15:56 2013 from localhost
B: command not found
B: command not found
D: command not found
D: command not found
D: command not found
D: command not found

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308107/cant-ssh-localhost/308126#comment388234_308118) it appeared that your OpenSSH server configuration file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) is empty. Reinstall the configuration file by purging and reinstalling:

1. Remove the configuration file:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
2. purge:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
   ```
3. install:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   ```

This *may* not work, instead, then follow: [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66533/88802)

Comment: Thanks all, i guess its running now. i removed, purged and reinstalled. here's the output :ssh localhost root@localhost's password: Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686) * Documentation: help.ubuntu.com Last login: Fri Jun 14 17:15:56 2013 from localhost B: command not found B: command not found D: command not found D: command not found D: command not found D: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You connect using the following command

```
ssh username@127.0.0.1
```

Change username to whatever user is available on that computer

Comment: Hello Meer Borg, i did what you asked me to do. ran ssh -vvv kunal@127.0.0.1 but alas, sorry to say, i got the same log on terminal which i was getting earlier. till the last 2nd line, it goes like this : debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer and then the same error. Thanks again. though, i am open to suggestions if any.

Comment: Specifying the username explicitly does not make any difference here. `ssh` will use the current username by default.

Comment: @KunalSangwan Check the /var/log/auth.log file to see if there is anything that is logged at the time you try to log into that command `cat /var/log/auth.log | tail`

Comment: Thanks all, i guess its running now. i removed, purged and reinstalled. here's the output :ssh localhost root@localhost's password: Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686) * Documentation: help.ubuntu.com Last login: Fri Jun 14 17:15:56 2013 from localhost B: command not found B: command not found D: command not found D: command not found D: command not found D: command not found

Answer (score 0):

In you log I see following message
`debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "localhost" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"`

so that means machine is trying to look for hosts and more over connection has been attempted check for ssh logs and post here (that will reveal if any connection reached localhost or not)

also 
check if port 22 is open for incoming connections at your end because it seems that port 22 is closed at your end  for incoming connections check if by the way you are running any kind of firewall (IPTABLES) etc which blocks it

what is the exact message you get on screen when you do ssh user@localhost you typed `ssh -vvv localhost` it doesnt makes any sense `ssh -vvv user@localhost` should be the thing

Comment: my port 22 is open here's what i got : netstat -anp | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      556/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      556/sshd

Comment: try removing and reinstalling OpenSSh

Comment: Though one thing : /etc/ssh/sshd_config is empty ?  is that normal ?

Comment: @KunalSangwan No. How did that happen? Please add such info to your question!

Comment: did once removed and reinstalled open ssh

Comment: @KunalSangwan Then *purge* instead of regular *remove* action! This will reinstall configuration files.

Comment: @gertvdijk can you be kind enough to specify the command please.

Comment: Though i wonder Y SSHD_CONFIG IS EMPTY ?? I opened it via gedit,and it came out complete blanks like a white sheet ?nothing written at all ?

Comment: Thanks all, i guess its running now. i removed, purged and reinstalled. here's the output :ssh localhost root@localhost's password: Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686) * Documentation: help.ubuntu.com Last login: Fri Jun 14 17:15:56 2013 from localhost B: command not found B: command not found D: command not found D: command not found D: command not found D: command not found