# My sshd_config file is empty is this correct?

Tags: server, ssh

I just finished installing Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 and was setting up ssh.

When I did 
`$ sudo vi etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I get something with no lines and the words [New Directory]

Is this the way it should be? My `ssh_config` file is ok. There's text in it.

Did I go wrong anywhere? How do I set this right?

Comment: LOL, I've stumbled upon this question for the 3rd time in last 24 hours, because I actually get empty `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` after reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is a bit more simple than currently being suggested. Look at your command again:

```
sudo vi etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

There's no leading `/`. That means `vi` is trying to open `<current-path>/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so unless you're at `/`, it won't work.

The fix is to just specify the proper path:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: and you are probably right (as always) :)

Comment: Thanks for that Oli. Now it's there. I can see the sshd file's contents. But the ssh_config is gone. I'll reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Or you could just [reinstall the right package with its config](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files):
`sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall openssh-client`

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is absolutely normal there is nothing to do with it.. no worry..

it is basically OpenSSH SSH daemon configuration file

Comment: So when I need to add rules like AllowUsers tom jerry do I add them to the ssh_config file or the sshd_config file

Comment: yes u can just make sure you write it properly..

Comment: This is not true, after installing the ssh server the configuration file is not empty and you do not need to write everything by hand, it comes pre-configured!

Comment: @maythux well, it does provide answer, even though it's wrong. In that case, downvoting is the right approach.