# Can't install apache2 again

Tags: apache2

I have previously had apache2 installed, I upgraded to php5.5 and this broke my install so i tried to fix a few files. But that didnt work, I autoremoved apache but I still get this error when I try to install:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
/etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you remove and re-install Apache it does not remove or over write config files.

see [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

If that fails, update your question with error messages

Comment: Do you mean `sudo apt-get purge apache2` and `sudo apt-get install apache2`? (If so, that should work, though I'd suggest `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install apache2`, which does it in "one step" and, more importantly, makes sure any necessary package files are downloaded before performing the original package removal.)

Answer (score 4):

Use command lines below:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And finally, install `apache2` again: `sudo apt-get -y install apache2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall apache2.2-common
```

It will reinstall apache packages and restore all configuration files in `/etc/apache2`.

Comment: +1 This what you should do if you have to restore config files.