# How to install more voices to Espeak?

Tags: text-to-speech, espeak

Could you please help me to install voices from [here](http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/mbrcopybin.html), I read [the manual](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/mbrola.html) But I don't know how can 'Get the en1'.

Comment: I've seen ways to play with espeak with sox post-filters if you just want to modify a voice, use swift from cepstral to use more human sounding voices, or plug cepstral voices in to festival for use with IVRs.  I haven't seen a way to plug more human voices in to espeak though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Download: http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/bin/pclinux/mbr301h.zip
2. Copy text to run in terminal line by line:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   unzip mbr301h.zip
   sudo cp mbrola-linux-i386 /usr/bin/mbrola
   ```
3. Download: http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/dba/en1/en1-980910.zip
4. Copy text to run in terminal line by line:

   ```
   unzip en1-980910.zip
   cp en1/en1 /usr/share/mbrola/en1
   ```
5. Now run espeak, with options

   ```
   espeak -v mb-en1 "Hello world"
   ```
6. Nice, but it seems he is reading too fast, try:

   ```
   espeak -v mb-en1 -s 120 "Hello world"
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much, Do you know any other way to improve voice quality and pronunciation?

Comment: @Daniyal : You can generate phonems with `espeak` and process them through [mbrola](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html) : `espeak -v mb-en1 -s 120 "Hello world" --pho|mbrola /usr/share/mbrola/en1 output.wav` (note the addition of `--pho` option to `espeak`).

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou No I can't, got this error: `FATAL ERROR : cannot find file /usr/share/mbrola/en1 !
mbrola: FATAL ERROR : cannot find file /usr/share/mbrola/voices/en1 !
mbrowrap error: mbrola exited with status 216
mbrola voice not found
` I don't know what you want but may be you can use of it `espeak -v mb-us2 -s 120 "Hello world"  -w output.wav --pho`

Comment: @Daniyal : it means you have the `en1` voice neither in `/usr/share/mbrola` (which you should if you followed step 4 of Mateo's reply) nor in `/usr/share/mbrola/voices`.  Either fix that (by creating the directory manually and copying voices there) or replace `/usr/share/mbrola/en1` by the path to an mbrola voice already installed.  It's really worth it, voice is much smoother with `mbrola` (though not perfect yet).

Comment: Thanks so much! Been dependent on Ivona for several years and although mbrola is a bit of a step down, it's still quite good for a FOSS alternative I can trust.

Comment: It's down for me but I managed to find it on the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180627172600/http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/bin/pclinux/mbr301h.zip

Comment: Here's the second file on the wayback maching - https://web.archive.org/web/20160706052143/http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/dba/en1/en1-980910.zip

Answer (score 4):

you can install embrola voices executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mbrola mbrola-en1
```

for more information visit the offical repo from github

[espeak docs and man pages](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/blob/master/docs/mbrola.md#installation-of-standard-packages)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be available on mine. Is it in the non-free repositories?

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx i got the server of united states, actually really i dont know if its free or non-free, in the command `apt-cache show  mbrola` it appears that this is the official repository https://github.com/numediart/MBROLA

Answer (score 2):

This process works on **20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)**:

### Find your voice

Find the desired mbrola voice by visiting the github:

https://github.com/numediart/MBROLA-voices

Locate and document the desired voice. For this example, I'm going to use *British English*, which is "en1".

### Get dependencies

Install the dependent applicatons:

```
sudo apt install -y espeak mbrola mbrola-en1 speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
```

### Edit speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf

To keep it simple, we'll paste our config at the top of speechd.conf and comment-out one setting in speechd.conf.

So open speechd.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf
```

Paste the following at the top of the document:

```
# Enable British English "en1"
AddModule "espeak-mbrola-generic"    "sd_generic"   "espeak-mbrola-generic.conf"
DefaultModule espeak-mbrola-generic
LanguageDefaultModule "en1"  "espeak-mbrola-generic"
```

Now search using "Ctrl+W" and copy/paste:

```
DefaultModule espeak-ng
```

Now comment it out by adding a hash at the beginning, like this:

```
#DefaultModule espeak-ng
```

Now save speechd.conf in nano:

- Press Ctrl+X
- Press "Y" to overwrite
- Press Enter to save and close nano

### Start the speech-dispatcher daemon

Start the daemon paste in the command:

```
sudo speech-dispatcher -d
```

This *should* start the speech daemon.

### Testing mbrola? I don't know how.

Testing the new British English voice in espeak will not produce your changes; it will be the default *espeak* voice, not the "en1", British English voice you're now using for *mbrola*.

I don't know how to test mbrola, so I will just continue on with *my implementation of mobrola-en1.*

### Speak Text for Okular

If you're interested in using a PDF Reader that has a "text to speech" feature, install Okular:

```
sudo apt install okular
```

Now, open a PDF and:

- Press "Ctrl+3" to set tool to "Area Selection"
- Click & drag a box over a section of text you want Okular to read
- After the context menu appears, select "Speak Text"

### Success!

You've now successfully setup text to speech, using speech-dispatcher, espeak, mbrola, and mbrola-en1 using Okular through the Ubuntu Package Repository.

### Adjust the speed of reading

By default, mbrola-en1 reads rather quickly. To "slow down" the speed, espeak--mbrola-generic config.

```
sudo nano /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/espeak-mbrola-generic.conf
```

With the config open in nano,

- Press "Ctrl+W"
- Paste "GenericRateAdd" and enter

Set GenericRateAdd to a number between 80 and 320

```
GenericRateAdd          200
```

#### Adjust pitch

Below GenericRateAdd, you can also adjust Pitch:

```
GenericPitchAdd         80
```

Now save espeak-mbrola-generic.conf in nano:

- Press Ctrl+X
- Press "Y" to overwrite
- Press Enter to save and close nano

### Adjust the word gap speed

espeak provides an easy way to adjust the time between words that text is read. To adjust said gap, open your module config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/espeak-mbrola-generic.conf
```

One of the first uncommented lines looks like this:

```
"echo \'$DATA\' | espeak -v mb-$VOICE -s $RATE -p $PITCH $PUNCT -q --stdin>
```

Add in an argument after espeak, "**-g 15**" to set the word gap time to 15ms (default is 10ms):

```
"echo \'$DATA\' | espeak -g 15 -v mb-$VOICE -s $RATE -p $PITCH $PUNCT -q --stdin>
```

### If you saved a bad config...

**Skip this if you've saved & successfully run a good speechd config.**

If you manage to screw up and save your config file, refer to [Jeremy Bicha's response](https://askubuntu.com/a/67028).

First remove the speechd.conf

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf
```

Reinstall speech-dispatcher and regenerate config

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" speech-dispatcher
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a copy of Mateo's answer as a single command and cleanup.

You will need `sudo` privileges to copy to `/usr/bin/`.

---

```
mkdir tmp_mbrola
cd tmp_mbrola
wget http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/bin/pclinux/mbr301h.zip
unzip mbr301h.zip
sudo cp mbrola-linux-i386 /usr/bin/mbrola
wget http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/dba/en1/en1-980910.zip
unzip en1-980910.zip
sudo mkdir /usr/share/mbrola
sudo cp en1/en1 /usr/share/mbrola/en1
cd ..
sudo rm -Rf ./tmp_mbrola/
espeak -v mb-en1 -s 160 "Hello world"
```

---

I am getting this error when text is read but it seems to work:

```
*** Error in `mbrola': free(): invalid pointer: 0x08af1dd8 ***
```

If anyone knows what is causing this error please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Gespeaker on Ubuntu 18.04

Hi all,
I have been looking for ways to improve the espeak user experience including modifying/adding new voices and came across this article regarding Gespeaker which is a graphical interface for espeak. It's easier to use especially for bits of text which you can cut and paste from a webpage and have read. To expand the text window to accommodate large chunks of texts click on the "advanced settings" button (see image).

There is an option for **variant** in the voice section (where you have male and female - which work). I don't know how to make use of this to add a variant (of a voice?). I will update this if I find a way.

To install Gespeaker, open Terminal and

$ **sudo apt-get install gespeaker**

You also need to install python-dbus

$ **sudo apt-get install python-dbus**

for the application to run.
[image]

Update.
I managed to add additional mbrola voices that can be used with Gespeaker.

This how. First install the mbrola text-to-speech engine.
Open Terminal and enter
$ **sudo apt install mbrola**
followed by pressing the return key.

You should see something this if the install ran okay
"MBROLA 3.01h - speech synthesizer
Author : Thierry Dutoit with help of AC/DC adaptator Vincent Pagel
Copyright (c) 95 Faculte Polytechnique de Mons (TCTS lab) - T.Dutoit...etc"

Next install a mbrola voice.
You can view a list of available voice packages here:
http://www.muflone.com/gespeaker/english/mbrola_voices/ubuntu1610
The last updates were for Ubuntu 16.10. I haven't found newer versions.

Install a voice package.For example to install the US english female voice run

$ **sudo apt install mbrola-us1**

Restart Gespeaker.

You should see the voice appear amongst the existing espeak voices in the  language bar of Gespeaker. See the image  below. [image]

I still don't know how to employ the "Variant" option.

Credits: https://vitux.com/convert-text-to-voice-with-espeak-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an updated version of [Mateo](https://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo)'s accepted answer. Since the ISIA Lab (formerly known as TCTS) is not hosting its website any more, we must download them from GitHub directly. Disclaimer, I am currently working in this lab, but not on that project.

1. Install the needed dependencies (see [MBROLA GitHub repository](https://github.com/numediart/MBROLA#compilation) for the details):

   ```bash
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install espeak make gcc git -y
   ```
2. Download, compile and install MBROLA:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/numediart/MBROLA.git
   cd MBROLA
   make
   cp Bin/mbrola /usr/bin/mbrola
   ```
3. Download the desired voice from the [MBROLA-voices GitHub repository](https://github.com/numediart/MBROLA-voices) (you can do it manually):

   ```bash
   mkdir /usr/share/mbrola/en1
   curl -L -o /usr/share/mbrola/us1/us1 https://github.com/numediart/MBROLA-voices/blob/master/data/en1/en1?raw=true
   ```

   Note: `/usr/share/mbrola/en1` is a folder, while your file's path will be `/usr/share/mbrola/en1/en1`. Don't forget to change `en1` with whatever voice you wish to use (also in the commands hereunder).
4. Now you can run `espeak`:

   ```bash
   espeak -v mb-en1 "Hello world"
   ```

   Mateo said the voice was reading too fast and proposed to set the speed using `-s 120`:

   ```bash
   espeak -v mb-en1 -s 120 "Hello world"
   ```
5. Bonus! If, like me, you have installed `MBROLA` and `espeak` on a remote headless server, you may prefer to generate a `.wav` file and use `scp` to download it to your local machine.

   Generate the file on the remote machine:

   ```
   ssh user@remote_machine_ip 'espeak -v mb-us1 -s 120 "Nice hat" --stdout > /tmp/file.wav && exit'
   ```

   Download the generated file:

   ```bash
   scp user@remote_machine_ip:/tmp/file.wav /local_machine/path/to/file.wav
   ```

Comment: I followed your instruction, I get follwing error and audio is not clear

`$ espeak-ng -v mb-us1 "Hello world"`
Erroe: `mbrola: Warning: w-r= unknown, replaced with _-_`, `mbrola: Warning: r=-l unknown, replaced with _-_`

Comment: @Porcupine you should ask your question on MBROLA repository (https://github.com/numediart/MBROLA).