# Login screen keeps coming back (bash_completion related)

Tags: bash, login

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. By accident I deleted `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`. I then restored it by copying that same file from another similar Linux machine (same OS).

Now I can't login because the login screen keeps coming back after each successful login. I tried both Xubunto session and Xfce.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) the output of `ls -l /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` and ii) the contents of your `~/.xsession-errors` file. You can use a live CD to get these if needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you think it's that file that's responsible, you could reset it back to the packaged defaults by reinstalling the `bash-completion` package. We have to be [a little more forceful](https://askubuntu.com/a/67028/449) to get it to copy the configuration back, but this should work:

```
sudo rm /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall bash-completion
```

Reboot and see where that gets you.

---

It has just struck me that you might have problems getting to a terminal to enter this! There are several options there but here are my favourite:

- [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)'s root console
- [A LiveCD/USB cross-mount/chroot](https://askubuntu.com/a/435347/449)

They should both set you up as root on your install, and from there you should be able to action a change. If nothing else just delete the current `bash_completion.sh` file. That should allow you to log back in normally, albeit without Bash autocompletes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of different things including removing that file but it didn't work.

Finally I solved my problem by deleting the .dmrc file in my home directory. I accessed tty1 console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and did it from there.

Thank you.