# Deleted /etc/apf/apf

Tags: 14.04, server, apf

OK, so I did something in the wrong place at the wrong time and ended up missing `/etc/apf/apf`.  Ouch.  `apf` is not running.  Can someone pastebin/send me that file?  Before my server dies from all sorts of attacks...

OK, to make it a good question: "How do I get this file back?", and I don't have a backup of it handy.

Ubuntu 14.04 Server x86_64
Intel 8-core Xeon @ 3.5GHz

I don't feel that this is a duplicate, because I cannot find this package using apt.  I tried that already.

Comment: I don't have it, but in the mean time, if you have a Live CD try booting another PC with it and install the firewall in a live session; or in a virtual machine, then just copy the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover the default version of some configuration file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627017/how-do-i-recover-the-default-version-of-some-configuration-file)

Comment: You mean this package? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apf-firewall

Comment: I tried that ^ and it didn't restore the config.  I figure that I must have a custom build of it (a lot of stuff on my server is custom - hard to fix, but high performing...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to reinstall the file as you don't have the backup. Please refer to the below URL to install the /etc/apf/apf file -

http://akyl.net/how-properly-install-apf-advanced-policy-firewall-centos-or-ubuntu

Comment: I'll try this Lizzy, and I hope it works!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  This worked!  If we ever run into each other in person, remind me to buy you a coffee.