# How to restore/recreate etc/nsswitch.conf files

Tags: restore

Accidently I corrupted my nsswithch.conf file and now my hosts are not working. How can I restore or recreate it?

Comment: `grep nsswitch.conf /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst` leads to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.postinst`, which lead to `/usr/share/libc-bin/nsswitch.conf` and  `/usr/share/base-files/nsswitch.conf`. The `libc-bin` post-installation script is more specific, so I'd use that.

Comment: @muru it may also be modified by the `libnss-mdns` postinst I think

Comment: This question is not a question of [that other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627017/how-do-i-recover-the-default-version-of-some-configuration-file), because the solutions listed there do not work for `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Indeed, `dpkg -S /etc/nsswitch.conf` does not return any results (on Artful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is relatively generic, I would copy it from a working system of the same Ubuntu release

This should at least get you going - it's the default from xenial and should work regardless on pretty much any version.

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis
```